# How to add a property to a module in boost::python?

Tags: c++, python, boost, boost-python

You can add a property to a class using a getter and a setter (in a simplistic case):

```
class<X>("X")
    .add_property("foo", &X::get_foo, &X::set_foo);
```

So then you can use it from python like this:

```
>>> x = mymodule.X()
>>> x.foo = 'aaa'
>>> x.foo
'aaa'
```

**But how to add a property to a module itself (not a class)?**

There is

```
scope().attr("globalAttr") = ??? something ???
```

and

```
def("globalAttr", ??? something ???);
```

I can add global functions and objects of my class using the above two ways, but can't seem to add properties the same way as in classes.

Answer (score 3):

`__getattr__` and `__setattr__` aren't called on modules, so you [can't do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447353/getattr-on-a-module) in ordinary Python without hacks (like storing a class in the module dictionary).  Given that, it's very unlikely there's an elegant way to do it in Boost Python either.

Answer (score 3):

[boost.python/HowTo](http://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/HowTo#mutable_C.2B-.2B-_object) on Python Wiki has an example of exposing C++ object as a module attribute inside `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE`:

```
namespace bp = boost::python;
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
    bp::scope().attr("my_attr") = bp::object(bp::ptr(&my_cpp_object));
}
```

To set the attribute outside of `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE` use

```
bp::import("example").attr("my_attr") = bp::object(bp::ptr(&my_cpp_object));
```

Now you can do in python something like

```
from example import my_attr
```

Of course, you need to register class of `my_cpp_object` in advance (e.g. you can do this inside the same `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE` call) and ensure C++ object lifetime exceeds that of the python module. You can use any `bp::object` instead of wrapping C++ one.

Note that `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE` swallows exceptions, so if you make a mistake, you don't receive any error indication and `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE`-generated function will just immediately return. To ease debugging of this case you can catch exceptions inside `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE` or temporary add some logging statement as a last line of `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE` to see that it is reached:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
    bp::scope().attr("my_attr2") = new int(1); // this will compile
    std::cout << "init finished\n"; // OOPS, this line will not be reached
}
```