# What is the pythonic way to setattr() for a module?

Tags: python, attributes, module

In a class method, I can add attributes using the built-in function:

```
setattr(self, "var_name", value).
```

If I want to do the same thing within a module, I can do something like:

```
globals()["var_name"] = value
```

Is this the best way to do this, or is there a more pythonic solution?

Comment: I believe the first way is the most Pythonic way. Although, I'm not sure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I call setattr() on the current module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933470/how-do-i-call-setattr-on-the-current-module)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your suggested approach

```
globals()["var_name"] = value
```

is indeed the most Pythonic way.  In particular, it's significantly more Pythonic than using [eval](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval), which would be your main (though not only) alternative.

However, if you still want to use `setattr`, you may do so by using [sys.modules](http://docs.python.org/library/sys#sys.modules) to get a reference to the current module object with the current module's `__name__` variable ([explained here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#modules)) as follows:

```
import sys
setattr(sys.modules[__name__], "var_name", value)
```