# How references to variables are resolved in Python

Tags: python, variables, python-2.7, scope, python-internals

This message is a a bit long with many examples, but I hope it
will help me and others to better grasp the full story of variables
and attribute lookup in Python 2.7.

I am using the terms of PEP 227
(http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0227/) for code blocks (such as
modules, class definition, function definitions, etc.) and
variable bindings (such as assignments, argument declarations, class
and function declaration, for loops, etc.)

I am using the terms variables for names that can be called without a
dot, and attributes for names that need to be qualified with an object
name (such as obj.x for the attribute x of object obj).

There are three scopes in Python for all code blocks, but the functions:

- Local
- Global
- Builtin

There are four blocks in Python for the functions only (according to
PEP 227):

- Local
- Enclosing functions
- Global
- Builtin

The rule for a variable to bind it to and find it in a block is
quite simple:

- any binding of a variable to an object in a block makes this variable
  local to this block, unless the variable is declared global (in that
  case the variable belongs to the global scope)
- a reference to a variable is looked up using the rule LGB (local,
  global, builtin) for all blocks, but the functions
- a reference to a variable is looked up using the rule LEGB (local,
  enclosing, global, builtin) for the functions only.

Let me know take examples validating this rule, and showing many
special cases. For each example, I will give my understanding. Please
correct me if I am wrong. For the last example, I don't understand the
outcome.

example 1:

```
x = "x in module"
class A():
    print "A: "  + x                    #x in module
    x = "x in class A"
    print locals()
    class B():
        print "B: " + x                 #x in module
        x = "x in class B"
        print locals()
        def f(self):
            print "f: " + x             #x in module
            self.x = "self.x in f"
            print x, self.x
            print locals()

>>>A.B().f()
A: x in module
{'x': 'x in class A', '__module__': '__main__'}
B: x in module
{'x': 'x in class B', '__module__': '__main__'}
f: x in module
x in module self.x in f
{'self': <__main__.B instance at 0x00000000026FC9C8>}
```

There is no nested scope for the classes (rule LGB) and a function in
a class cannot access the attributes of the class without using a
qualified name (self.x in this example). This is well described in
PEP227.

example 2:

```
z = "z in module"
def f():
    z = "z in f()"
    class C():
        z = "z in C"
        def g(self):
            print z
            print C.z
    C().g()
f()
>>> 
z in f()
z in C
```

Here variables in functions are looked up using the LEGB rule, but if
a class is in the path, the class arguments are skipped. Here again,
this is what PEP 227 is explaining.

example 3:

```
var = 0
def func():
    print var
    var = 1
>>> func()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#102>", line 1, in <module>
func()
  File "C:/Users/aa/Desktop/test2.py", line 25, in func
print var
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'var' referenced before assignment
```

We expect with a dynamic language such as python that everything is
resolved dynamically. But this is not the case for functions. Local
variables are determined at compile time. PEP 227  and 
http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/executionmodel.html describe this
behavior this way

"If a name binding operation occurs anywhere within a code block, all
uses of the name within the block are treated as references to the
current block."

example 4:

```
x = "x in module"
class A():
    print "A: " + x
    x = "x in A"
    print "A: " + x
    print locals()
    del x
    print locals()
    print "A: " + x
>>> 
A: x in module
A: x in A
{'x': 'x in A', '__module__': '__main__'}
{'__module__': '__main__'}
A: x in module
```

But we see here that this statement in PEP227 "If a name binding
operation occurs anywhere within a code block, all uses of the name
within the block are treated as references to the current block."  is
wrong when the code block is a class. Moreover, for classes, it seems
that local name binding is not made at compile time, but during
execution using the class namespace. In that respect,
PEP227 and the execution model in the Python doc is misleading and for
some parts wrong.

example 5:

```
x = 'x in module'
def  f2():
    x = 'x in f2'
    def myfunc():
        x = 'x in myfunc'
        class MyClass(object):
            x = x
            print x
        return MyClass
    myfunc()
f2()
>>> 
x in module
```

my understanding of this code is the following. The instruction x = x
first look up the object the right hand x of the expression is referring
to. In that case, the object is looked up locally in the class, then
following the rule LGB it is looked up in the global scope, which is
the string 'x in module'. Then a local attribute x to MyClass is
created in the class dictionary and pointed to the string object.

example 6:

Now here is an example I cannot explain.
It is very close to example 5, I am just changing the local MyClass
attribute from x to y.

```
x = 'x in module'
def  f2():
    x = 'x in f2'
    def myfunc():
        x = 'x in myfunc'
        class MyClass(object):
            y = x
            print y
        return MyClass
    myfunc()
f2()
>>>
x in myfunc
```

Why in that case the x reference in MyClass is looked up in the
innermost function?

Comment: It's very hard to tell what is supposed to be going on in the last few examples with the indentation the way it is - could you fix it?  (Remember, a 4 space indentation creates a code block - every space after that is shown as whitespace in the code sample).

Comment: This looks like a very interesting question, but please fix the indentation.

Comment: @SeanVieira thanks for noticing. I had many tabs instead of spaces. It is fixed now.

Comment: An *excellent* question - I would that could upvote it 10 times, but +1 until I can!

Comment: Speaking as someone who has programmed a lot of python without ever deconstructing the PEP (never was big on reading user manuals) example 6 seems intuitive to me, whereas example 5 seems to violate the principle of least surprise — not the other way round.  It seems unintuitive that a class scope should ever depart from function-scope behaviour and check the global scope *before* enclosing scopes. Doubtless there are (historical?) reasons for it.  But the particular example that triggers it, `x=x` is a pretty nasty, unmaintainable idiom anyway.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In two words, the difference between example 5 and example 6 is that in example 5 the variable `x` is also assigned to in the same scope, while not in example 6.  This triggers a difference that can be understood by historical reasons.

This raises UnboundLocalError:

```
x = "foo"
def f():
    print x
    x = 5
f()
```

instead of printing "foo".  It makes a bit of sense, even if it seems strange at first: the function f() defines the variable `x` locally, even if it is after the print, and so any reference to `x` in the same function must be to that local variable.  At least it makes sense in that it avoids strange surprizes if you have by mistake reused the name of a global variable locally, and are trying to use both the global and the local variable.  This is a good idea because it means that we can statically know, just by looking at a variable, *which* variable it means.  For example, we know that `print x` refers to the local variable (and thus may raise UnboundLocalError) here:

```
x = "foo"
def f():
    if some_condition:
        x = 42
    print x
f()
```

Now, this rule doesn't work for class-level scopes: there, we want expressions like `x = x` to work, capturing the global variable `x` into the class-level scope.  This means that class-level scopes don't follow the basic rule above: we can't know if `x` in this scope refers to some outer variable or to the locally-defined `x` --- for example:

```
class X:
    x = x     # we want to read the global x and assign it locally
    bar = x   # but here we want to read the local x of the previous line

class Y:
    if some_condition:
        x = 42
    print x     # may refer to either the local x, or some global x

class Z:
    for i in range(2):
        print x    # prints the global x the 1st time, and 42 the 2nd time
        x = 42
```

So in class scopes, a different rule is used: where it would normally raise UnboundLocalError --- and only in that case --- it instead looks up in the module globals.  That's all: it doesn't follow the chain of nested scopes.

Why not?  I actually doubt there is a better explanation that "for historical reasons".  In more technical terms, it could consider that the variable `x` is both locally defined in the class scope (because it is assigned to) *and* should be passed in from the parent scope as a lexically nested variable (because it is read).  It would be possible to implement it by using a different bytecode than `LOAD_NAME` that looks up in the local scope, and falls back to using the nested scope's reference if not found.

**EDIT:** thanks wilberforce for the reference to http://bugs.python.org/issue532860.  We may have a chance to get some discussion reactivated with the proposed new bytecode, if we feel that it should be fixed after all (the bug report considers killing support for `x = x` but was closed for fear of breaking too much existing code; instead what I'm suggesting here would be to make `x = x` work in more cases).  Or I may be missing another fine point...

**EDIT2:** it seems that CPython did precisely that in the current 3.4 trunk: http://bugs.python.org/issue17853 ... or not?  They introduced the bytecode for a slightly different reason and don't use it systematically...

Comment: A key difference is that statements and expressions in the body of a function are evaluated when the function is *called*; the statements and expressions in the body of a `class` statement are executed as part of the `class` statement (i.e., earlier). In the function, `some_condition` may or may not be true, so `x` needs to have the same scope each time. The `class` statement is executed once, so by the time `print x` is reached, we know if `x` is local or global by the time we reach it.

Comment: My point is that in functions we know if `x` is a local or global by the time the bytecode compiler runs, before evaluating anything at all.  More complicated examples can be drawn with a `for` loop in the `class` body where the same use of the same variable `x` is not always resolved to the same scope.

Answer (score 23):

In an ideal world, you'd be right and some of the inconsistencies you found would be wrong. However, CPython has optimized some scenarios, specifically function locals. These optimizations, together with how the compiler and evaluation loop interact and historical precedent, lead to the confusion.

Python translates code to bytecodes, and those are then interpreted by a interpreter loop. The 'regular' opcode for accessing a name is `LOAD_NAME`, which looks up a variable name as you would in a dictionary. `LOAD_NAME` will first look up a name as a local, and if that fails, looks for a global. `LOAD_NAME` throws a `NameError` exception when the name is not found.

For nested scopes, looking up names outside of the current scope is implemented using closures; if a name is not assigned to but is available in a nested (not global) scope, then such values are handled as a closure. This is needed because a parent scope can hold different values for a given name at different times; two calls to a parent function can lead to different closure values. So Python has `LOAD_CLOSURE`, `MAKE_CLOSURE` and `LOAD_DEREF` opcodes for that situation; the first two opcodes are used in loading and creating a closure for a nested scope, and the `LOAD_DEREF` will load the closed-over value when the nested scope needs it.

Now, `LOAD_NAME` is relatively slow; it will consult two dictionaries, which means it has to hash the key first and run a few equality tests (if the name wasn't interned). If the name isn't local, then it has to do this again for a global. For functions, that can potentially be called tens of thousands of times, this can get tedious fast. So function locals have special opcodes. Loading a local name is implemented by `LOAD_FAST`, which looks up local variables *by index* in a special local names array. This is much faster, but it does require that the compiler first has to see if a name is a local and not global. To still be able to look up global names, another opcode `LOAD_GLOBAL` is used. The compiler explicitly optimizes for this case to generate the special opcodes. `LOAD_FAST` will throw an `UnboundLocalError` exception when there is not yet a value for the name.

Class definition bodies on the other hand, although they are treated much like a function, do not get this optimization step. Class definitions are not meant to be called all that often; most modules create classes *once*, when imported. Class scopes don't count when nesting either, so the rules are simpler. As a result, class definition bodies do not act like functions when you start mixing scopes up a little.

So, for non-function scopes, `LOAD_NAME` and `LOAD_DEREF` are used for locals and globals, and for closures, respectively. For functions, `LOAD_FAST`, `LOAD_GLOBAL` and `LOAD_DEREF` are used instead.

Note that class bodies are executed as soon as Python executes the `class` line! So in example 1, `class B` inside `class A` is executed as soon as `class A` is executed, which is when you import the module. In example 2, `C` is not executed until `f()` is called, not before.

Lets walk through your examples:

1. You have nested a class `A.B` in a class `A`. Class bodies do not form nested scopes, so even though the `A.B` class body is executed when class `A` is executed, the compiler will use `LOAD_NAME` to look up `x`. `A.B().f()` is a *function* (bound to the `B()` instance as a method), so it uses `LOAD_GLOBAL` to load `x`. We'll ignore attribute access here, that's a very well defined name pattern.
2. Here `f().C.z` is at class scope, so the function `f().C().g()` will skip the `C` scope and look at the `f()` scope instead, using `LOAD_DEREF`.
3. Here `var` was determined to be a local by the compiler because you assign to it within the scope. Functions are optimized, so `LOAD_FAST` is used to look up the local and an exception is thrown.
4. Now things get a little weird. `class A` is executed at class scope, so `LOAD_NAME` is being used. `A.x` was deleted from the locals dictionary for the scope, so the second access to `x` results in the global `x` being found instead; `LOAD_NAME` looked for a local first and didn't find it there, falling back to the global lookup.

   Yes, this appears inconsistent with the documentation. Python-the-language and CPython-the implementation are clashing a little here. You are, however, pushing the boundaries of what is possible and practical in a dynamic language; checking if `x` should have been a local in `LOAD_NAME` would be possible but takes precious execution time for a corner case that most developers will never run into.
5. Now you are confusing the compiler. You used `x = x` in the class scope, and thus you are setting a *local* from a name outside of the scope. The compiler finds `x` is a local here (you assign to it), so it never considers that it could also be a scoped name. The compiler uses `LOAD_NAME` for all references to `x` in this scope, because this is not an optimized function body.

   When executing the class definition, `x = x` first requires you to *look up `x`*, so it uses `LOAD_NAME` to do so. No `x` is defined, `LOAD_NAME` doesn't find a local, so the *global* `x` is found. The resulting value is stored as a local, which *happens* to be named `x` as well. `print x` uses `LOAD_NAME` again, and now finds the new local `x` value.
6. Here you did not confuse the compiler. You are creating a local `y`, `x` is not local, so the compiler recognizes it as a scoped name from parent function `f2().myfunc()`. `x` is looked up with `LOAD_DEREF` from the closure, and stored in `y`.

You could see the confusion between 5 and 6 as a bug, albeit one that is not worth fixing in my opinion. It was certainly filed as such, see [issue 532860](http://bugs.python.org/issue532860) in the Python bug tracker, it has been there for over 10 years now.

The compiler could check for a scoped name `x` even when `x` is *also* a local, for that first assignment in example 5. Or `LOAD_NAME` could check if the name is meant to be a local, really, and throw an `UnboundLocalError` if no local was found, at the expense of more performance. Had this been in a function scope, `LOAD_FAST` would have been used for example 5, and an `UnboundLocalError` would be thrown immediately.

However, as the referenced bug shows, for historical reasons the behaviour is retained. There probably is code out there today that'll break were this bug fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, I still don't get why in example 6, x is considered a scoped name. x is referred from within a class, my understanding is that in this case it should be looked up locally, then globally. Also, PEP 227 is supposed to be for functions only, not for classes, and we see in example 1 that classes do not use enclosing scope look up. What is special in example 6 that explain that a referred variable in a class is considered a scoped variable?

Comment: No, PEP 227 applies to class definitions too; the only exception is that class definitions do not form a scope for nested code blocks. So in example 1, the class `A` definition does not count as a parent scope for names in class `B`, which is why `x` in `B` is not using `A.x` but looks at the global `x`. In example 6, the parent function **does** form a scope, so `x` is looked up from that scope. The only exception here is example 5, where `x` is really a local in `B`, and the `LOAD_NAME` opcode is used to handle this. The fact that `x = x` works *at all* is perhaps a bug there.

Comment: Ok, I missed this subtlety and erroneously believed that if classes do not form a scope for nested code block, they completely escape scoped name resolution. This is definitively neither straightforward, intuitive, nor well documented. These issues deserve examples and I hope my post will help in that respect. Thanks for all the clarifications.

Answer (score 7):

Long story short, this is a corner case of Python's scoping that is a bit inconsistent, but has to be kept for backwards compatibility (and because it's not that clear what the right answer should be). You can see lots of the [original discussion](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2002-April/023427.html) about it on the Python mailing list when PEP 227 was being implemented, and some in the [bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue532860) for which this behaviour is the fix.

We can work out why there's a difference using the [`dis`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) module, which lets us look inside code objects to see the bytecode a piece of code has been compiled to. I'm on Python 2.6, so the details of this might be slightly different - but I see the same behaviour, so I think it's probably close enough to 2.7.

The code that initialises each nested `MyClass` lives in a code object that you can get to via the attributes of the top-level functions. (I'm renaming the functions from example 5 and example 6 to `f1` and `f2` respectively.)

The code object has a `co_consts` tuple, which contains the `myfunc` code object, which in turn has the code that runs when `MyClass` gets created:

```
In [20]: f1.func_code.co_consts
Out[20]: (None,
 'x in f2',
 <code object myfunc at 0x1773e40, file "<ipython-input-3-6d9550a9ea41>", line 4>)
In [21]: myfunc1_code = f1.func_code.co_consts[2]
In [22]: MyClass1_code = myfunc1_code.co_consts[3]
In [23]: myfunc2_code = f2.func_code.co_consts[2]
In [24]: MyClass2_code = myfunc2_code.co_consts[3]
```

Then you can see the difference between them in bytecode using `dis.dis`:

```
In [25]: from dis import dis
In [26]: dis(MyClass1_code)
  6           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (__name__)
              3 STORE_NAME               1 (__module__)

  7           6 LOAD_NAME                2 (x)
              9 STORE_NAME               2 (x)

  8          12 LOAD_NAME                2 (x)
             15 PRINT_ITEM          
             16 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             17 LOAD_LOCALS         
             18 RETURN_VALUE        

In [27]: dis(MyClass2_code)
  6           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (__name__)
              3 STORE_NAME               1 (__module__)

  7           6 LOAD_DEREF               0 (x)
              9 STORE_NAME               2 (y)

  8          12 LOAD_NAME                2 (y)
             15 PRINT_ITEM          
             16 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             17 LOAD_LOCALS         
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

So the only difference is that in `MyClass1`, `x` is loaded using the `LOAD_NAME` op, while in `MyClass2`, it's loaded using `LOAD_DEREF`. `LOAD_DEREF` looks up a name in an enclosing scope, so it gets 'x in myfunc'. `LOAD_NAME` doesn't follow nested scopes - since it can't see the `x` names bound in `myfunc` or `f1`, it gets the module-level binding.

Then the question is, why does the code of the two versions of `MyClass` get compiled to two different opcodes? In `f1` the binding is shadowing `x` in the class scope, while in `f2` it's binding a new name. If the `MyClass` scopes were nested functions instead of classes, the `y = x` line in `f2` would be compiled the same, but the `x = x` in `f1` would be a `LOAD_FAST` - this is because the compiler would know that `x` is bound in the function, so it should use the `LOAD_FAST` to retrieve a local variable. This would fail with an `UnboundLocalError` when it was called.

```
In [28]:  x = 'x in module'
def  f3():
    x = 'x in f2'
    def myfunc():
        x = 'x in myfunc'
        def MyFunc():
            x = x
            print x
        return MyFunc()
    myfunc()
f3()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-9f04105d64cc> in <module>()
      9         return MyFunc()
     10     myfunc()
---> 11 f3()

<ipython-input-29-9f04105d64cc> in f3()
      8             print x
      9         return MyFunc()
---> 10     myfunc()
     11 f3()

<ipython-input-29-9f04105d64cc> in myfunc()
      7             x = x
      8             print x
----> 9         return MyFunc()
     10     myfunc()
     11 f3()

<ipython-input-29-9f04105d64cc> in MyFunc()
      5         x = 'x in myfunc'
      6         def MyFunc():
----> 7             x = x
      8             print x
      9         return MyFunc()

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

This fails because the `MyFunc` function then uses `LOAD_FAST`:

```
In [31]: myfunc_code = f3.func_code.co_consts[2]
MyFunc_code = myfunc_code.co_consts[2]
In [33]: dis(MyFunc_code)
  7           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  8           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              9 PRINT_ITEM          
             10 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             11 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```

(As an aside, it's not a big surprise that there should be a difference in how scoping interacts with code in the body of classes and code in a function. You can tell this because bindings at the class level aren't available in methods - method scopes aren't nested inside the class scope in the same way as nested functions are. You have to explicitly reach them via the class, or by using `self.` (which will fall back to the class if there's not also an instance-level binding).)

Comment: Man, bad luck on this one - I put all this work into an answer, and who else jumps in? One of the lead developers on the fastest Python implementation, who's had to replicate lots of CPython quirks like this one for compatibility's sake. And Martijn Pieters, who has 182k, because he presumably always gives fantastic answers like the one he did here. Oh well!