# Capturing Value instead of Reference in Lambdas

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda

I was slightly surprised by this example given by Eli Bendersky (http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/the-scope-of-index-variables-in-pythons-for-loops/)

```
>>> def foo():
...     lst = []
...     for i in range(4):
...         lst.append(lambda: i)
...     print([f() for f in lst])
...
>>> foo()
[3, 3, 3, 3]
```

But when I thought about it, it made some sense — the lambda is capturing a reference to i rather than i's value.

So a way to get around this is the following:

```
>>> def foo():
...     lst = []
...     for i in range(4):
...         lst.append((lambda a: lambda: a)(i))
...     print([f() for f in lst])
...
>>> foo()
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

It appears that the reason that this works is that when i is provided to the outer lambda, the outer lambda creates a scope and dereferences i, setting a to i. Then, the inner lambda, which is returned, holds a reference to a.

Is this a correct explanation?

Comment: Worth reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246523/how-references-to-variables-are-resolved-in-python/20250802#20250802 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/14414638/1252759

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Default param is an another way to catch a value:

```
lst.append(lambda i=i: i)
```

Answer (score 3):

> It appears that the reason that this works is that when i is provided
>   to the outer lambda, the outer lambda creates a scope and dereferences
>   i, setting a to i. Then, the inner lambda, which is returned, holds a
>   reference to a.
>
> Is this a correct explanation?

I don't like it.  Python does not pass by reference:

```
def func(x):
    x = 10

num = 3
func(num)

print num  #=>3
```

As a result, the terms *referenc*e and *dereference* are not in the python lexicon.  Or, you could say that python *always* dereferences a function argument before assigning it to a parameter variable--so your explanation doesn't really explain anything.

The reason the example works is because of the rule:

> A function's local variables are destroyed after it finishes executing.

A function's local variables include its parameter variables.  Every time the outer lambda executes, a new 'a' variable is created.  As a result, each inner lambda closes over a different 'a' variable.

You did allude to that state of affairs:

> the outer lambda creates a scope

...

> the lambda is capturing a reference to i rather than i's value.

Or, as I like to phrase it.

> A closure closes over variables--not values.

That is the way closures work in most languages(an exception being perl, where closures close over values).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks correct. If you are familiar with javascript and know closures, you will notice how similar they are.

If not - there is a nice [explanation on SO regarding JS closures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1090562) and the concept is absolutely the same (as well as the explanation and even wrong and correct usage).

Comment: Yep! I am familiar with the concept of the closure!