# Why does assigning to the variable after the `print` statement in a local class definition change the printed value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does this function output `0 1`?

Why is a class in a function behaving like a function? Why didn't I have to call A like a function?

How does the assignment statement after `print()` affect the values of `x` and `y`? When I assign value to `x`, `x` becomes 0 and if I assign a value to `y`, `y` becomes 0.

```
x = 0
y = 0

def f():
  x = 1
  y = 1
  class A:
    print(x,y)
    x = 99

f()
```

Comment: The Python interpreter makes optimisations as to where to look for variables depending on if it sees that variable being assigned to. The very existence of a line `x = ...` anywhere in a function/class changes the bytecode that Python generates to load `x` from `locals`, because there is no `y = ...` the bytecode generated loads `y` from `globals`. This is a good video to watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DlgbPLvBs30&ab_channel=CodingTech

Comment: @IainShelvington: but that means that python must read the entire text of the definition of `class A` before it executes the `print(x,y)`. I had thought that python just executed lines as they were read.

Comment: @quamrana This variable lookup optimisation is pretty much the only "clever" thing the compiler does, for almost everything else your assumption is pretty safe

Comment: @quamrana The parser *does* read the entire file before the *runtime* starts executing the code. The file is not read and executed line by line.

Comment: Thanks @deceze: I keep reading different explanations which seem to conflict with each other. Ok, so python *does* read the *entire* file, but the runtime only executes bits at a time, ie a function definition is *executed* by *creating* the function as an object, but a function itself is not executed unless the code also calls that function.

Comment: @quamrana The parser turns the textual source code into a structure the computer can actually do something with. Part of that process is figuring out variables names and their scope. *Then* that structure is being evaluated and executed, at which point functions and classes are actually created as objects. Very generally speaking…

Comment: This is a relevant discussion: [How references to variables are resolved in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246523/how-references-to-variables-are-resolved-in-python)

Comment: By the way, I think your observation of the changes is wrong, on my machine assigning to whichever variable will use the global value of that variable, not others.

Answer (score 6):

From the Python 3.9 [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names) :

> If a name binding operation occurs anywhere within a code block, all uses of the name within the block are treated as references to the current block.

The line `x = 99` in the class definition, makes `x` local to the class block.

In a class block,

> References follow the normal rules for name resolution with an exception that unbound local variables are looked up in the global namespace.

At the point the `print(x,y)` is executed, `x` is an unbound local variable. It's value is looked up in the global namespace, where `x = 0`.

> When a name is used in a code block, it is resolved using the nearest enclosing scope.

When `print(x, y)` is executed, the value of `y` is looked up in the nearest enclosing scope, which is the body of `def f()`, where `y = 1`.

So `print(x, y)` outputs `0 1`.