# Python class scoping rules

Tags: python, scoping

**EDIT:** Looks like this is a very old "bug" or, actually, feature. See, e.g., [this mail](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2002-April/023428.html)

I am trying to understand the Python scoping rules. More precisely, I thought that I understand them but then I found this code [here](http://lackingrhoticity.blogspot.ch/2008/08/4-python-variable-binding-oddities.html):

```
x = "xtop"
y = "ytop"
def func():
    x = "xlocal"
    y = "ylocal"
    class C:
        print(x)
        print(y)
        y = 1
func()
```

In Python 3.4 the output is:

```
xlocal
ytop
```

If I replace the inner class by a function then it reasonably gives `UnboundLocalError`. Could you explain me why it behaves this strange way with classes and what is the reason for such choice of scoping rules?

Comment: It wont give any error unless you call the inner function

Comment: Interesting; `y` should be an unbound exception in the case of `y`, but it isn't even when you make `C` a global. Corner cases FTW! Class bodies are special; they do not create a new scope of their own. As such `y = 1` would make it a local, but until that point it is a global *in class statements **only***.

Comment: [9.2. Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) and [4.1. Naming and binding](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) are a start, you might need to re-read them often till it sinks in.

Comment: if it's actual python3 code, then it should be `print(x)` and `print(y)`. `print x` is python2 code.

Comment: thanks, @zmo . changed that. Actually it behaves same way in Python2

Comment: This question could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296677/creating-a-class-within-a-function-and-access-a-function-defined-in-the-containi

Comment: Thanks @Kasra . It is strange however that the example 3 in that question works only in python3.4 and does not work in python3.1

Comment: ```dis.dis(func)``` with and without the ```y=1``` assignment in ```C``` shows that the former  only loads a closure for ```x``` and the latter loads a closure for ```x``` and ```y``` when ```C``` gets *built*.  Thought that was interesting though it doesn't point to any *rule*.

Comment: Sounds like this is a bug and should be reported as such.

Comment: @Kasra: that is the Python **2.1** *What's New* document. That is ancient history, not a recent change.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505979/the-scope-of-names-defined-in-class-block-doesnt-extend-to-the-methods-blocks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**TL;DR**: This behaviour has existed since Python 2.1 [PEP 227: Nested Scopes](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.1.html#pep-227-nested-scopes), and was known back then. If a name is assigned to within a class body (like `y`), then it is assumed to be a local/global variable; if it is not assigned to (`x`), then it also can potentially point to a closure cell. The lexical variables do not show up as local/global names to the class body.

---

On Python 3.4, `dis.dis(func)` shows the following:

```
>>> dis.dis(func)
  4           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('xlocal')
              3 STORE_DEREF              0 (x)

  5           6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('ylocal')
              9 STORE_FAST               0 (y)

  6          12 LOAD_BUILD_CLASS
             13 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (x)
             16 BUILD_TUPLE              1
             19 LOAD_CONST               3 (<code object C at 0x7f083c9bbf60, file "test.py", line 6>)
             22 LOAD_CONST               4 ('C')
             25 MAKE_CLOSURE             0
             28 LOAD_CONST               4 ('C')
             31 CALL_FUNCTION            2 (2 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             34 STORE_FAST               1 (C)
             37 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             40 RETURN_VALUE
```

The `LOAD_BUILD_CLASS` loads the `builtins.__build_class__` on the stack; this is called with arguments `__build_class__(func, name)`; where `func` is the class body, and `name` is `'C'`. The class body is the constant #3 for the function `func`:

```
>>> dis.dis(func.__code__.co_consts[3])
  6           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (__name__)
              3 STORE_NAME               1 (__module__)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 ('func.<locals>.C')
              9 STORE_NAME               2 (__qualname__)

  7          12 LOAD_NAME                3 (print)
             15 LOAD_CLASSDEREF          0 (x)
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             21 POP_TOP

  8          22 LOAD_NAME                3 (print)
             25 LOAD_NAME                4 (y)
             28 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             31 POP_TOP

  9          32 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             35 STORE_NAME               4 (y)
             38 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             41 RETURN_VALUE
```

Within the class body, `x` is accessed with `LOAD_CLASSDEREF` (15) while `y` is load with `LOAD_NAME` (25). The `LOAD_CLASSDEREF` is a Python 3.4+ opcode for loading values from closure cells specifically within class bodies (in previous versions, the generic `LOAD_DEREF` was used); the `LOAD_NAME` is for loading values from *locals* and then *globals*. However closure cells show up neither as locals nor globals.

Now, because the name `y` is stored to within the class body (35), it is consistently being used as not a closure cell but a local/global name.
The closure cells do not show up as local variables to the class body.

This behaviour has been true [ever since implementing PEP 227 - nested scopes](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2002-April/023428.html). And back then BDFL stated that this should not be fixed - and thus it has been for these 13+ years.

---

The only change since PEP 227 is the addition of `nonlocal` in Python 3; if one uses it within the class body, the class body can set the values of the cells within the containing scope:

```
x = "xtop"
y = "ytop"
def func():
    x = "xlocal"
    y = "ylocal"
    class C:
        nonlocal y  # y here now refers to the outer variable
        print(x)
        print(y)
        y = 1

    print(y)
    print(C.y)

func()
```

The output now is

```
xlocal
ylocal
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    func()
  File "test.py", line 13, in func
    print(C.y)
AttributeError: type object 'C' has no attribute 'y'
```

That is, `print(y)` read the value of the cell `y` of the containing scope, and `y = 1` set the value in that cell; in this case, no attribute was created for the class `C`.

Comment: It seems that I understood your explanation. Since `y` is stored it "bypasses" the usual mechanism. But doesn't it look like a bug to you?

Comment: If Guido says it is not a bug, then it is a feature. ;)

Comment: @ivanl: it is a known 'feature' of the implementation; see the email Antti links to. Class scopes are not like function scopes.

Answer (score 7):

First focus on the case of a closure -- a function within a function:

```
x = "xtop"
y = "ytop"
def func():
    x = "xlocal"
    y = "ylocal"
    def inner():
 #       global y
        print(x)
        print(y)
        y='inner y'
        print(y)
    inner()
```

Note the commented out `global` in `inner` If you run this, it replicates the `UnboundLocalError` you got. Why?

Run dis.dis on it:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(func)
  6           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('xlocal')
              3 STORE_DEREF              0 (x)

  7           6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('ylocal')
              9 STORE_FAST               0 (y)

  8          12 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (x)
             15 BUILD_TUPLE              1
             18 LOAD_CONST               3 (<code object inner at 0x101500270, file "Untitled 3.py", line 8>)
             21 LOAD_CONST               4 ('func.<locals>.inner')
             24 MAKE_CLOSURE             0
             27 STORE_FAST               1 (inner)

 14          30 LOAD_FAST                1 (inner)
             33 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             36 POP_TOP
             37 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             40 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note the different access mode of `x` vs `y` inside of `func`. The use of `y='inner y'` inside of `inner` has created the `UnboundLocalError`

Now uncomment `global y` inside of `inner`. Now you have unambiguously create `y` to be the top global version until resigned as `y='inner y'`

With `global` uncommented, prints:

```
xlocal
ytop
inner y
```

You *can* get a more sensible result with:

```
x = "xtop"
y = "ytop"
def func():
    global y, x
    print(x,y)
    x = "xlocal"
    y = "ylocal"
    def inner():
        global y
        print(x,y)
        y = 'inner y'
        print(x,y)
    inner()
```

Prints:

```
xtop ytop
xlocal ylocal
xlocal inner y
```

---

The analysis of the closure class is complicated by instance vs class variables and what / when a naked class (with no instance) is being executed.

The bottom line is the same: If you reference a name outside the local namespace and then assign to the same name locally you get a surprising result.

The 'fix' is the same: use the global keyword:

```
x = "xtop"
y = "ytop"
def func():
    global x, y
    x = "xlocal"
    y = "ylocal"
    class Inner:
        print(x, y)
        y = 'Inner_y'
        print(x, y)
```

Prints:

```
xlocal ylocal
xlocal Inner_y
```

You can read more about Python 3 scope rules in [PEP 3104](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/)

Comment: I understand the behavior for functions you pointed out. But it is still not clear what is the reason for _classes_ to behave differenly.

Comment: Classes will be similar but you need to further qualify instance vs class variables and nested class and nested instance variables. Bottom line is the same: The presence of the assignment of `y=1` make the reference `print(y)` above the assignment ambiguous inside the closure.

Comment: I would understand if my code would fail with `UnboundLocal` , but it looks really confusing how `y` can "bypass" y_local. Not failing with `UnboundLocal` really looks like a bug

Comment: There is a deference in how the interpreter treats each case, true. It is unusual to just have a class definition and execute code by its presence though.

Comment: PEP 3104 only introduces the `nonlocal` statement and doesn't actually explain the behaviour. The behaviour is a long-standing PEP 227 side-effect, 3104 never altered that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I did not claim 3104 was definitive -- only the most recent. It references PEP 227 and has a general overview.