# Python class and global vs local variables

Tags: python, class, namespaces, global-variables

I have a problem understanding what is happening with the outcome of the following pieces of code:

```
my_str = "outside func"
def func():
    my_str = "inside func"
    class C():
        print(my_str)
        print((lambda:my_str)())
        my_str = "inside C"
        print(my_str)
```

The output is:

```
outside func
inside func
inside C
```

Another piece of code is:

```
my_str = "not in class"
class C:
    my_str = "in the class"
    print([my_str for i in (1,2)])
    print(list(my_str for i in (1,2)))
```

The output is:

```
[‘in the class’, 'in the class’]
['not in class’, 'not in class’]
```

The question is:

1. What is happening here in each print() statement?
2. Can anyone explain **why** the print() statement get the string from the different namespaces?

---

Edit 1:

I think this is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29333359/python-class-scoping-rules) because I humbly think the answers there do not explain this variation:

```
my_str = "outside func"
def func():
    my_str = "inside func"
    class C():
        print(my_str)
        print((lambda:my_str)())
       #my_str = "inside C"
        print(my_str)
```

The output is:

```
inside func
inside func
inside func
```

Edit 2:

Indeed, this is a duplicate from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29333359/python-class-scoping-rules) because as Martijn Pieters says:

> The answer there states: If a name is assigned to within a class body,
>   almost at the start. You assigned to my_str, making it the same case
>   as y there. Commenting out that line means you are no longer assigning
>   to my_str, making it the same case as x.

---

Comment: @MartijnPieters Antti's beautiful answer there covers the first case. The second case trickles down to that but yet it is not a exact dupe. Perhaps I will leave that link there for future visitors to this question. (You've already prepared the draft rite ;))

Comment: @BhargavRao: sorry, I actually assumed you were linking to [Short Description of Python Scoping Rules](http://stackoverflow.com/q/291978)! This is indeed a dupe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are four scopes here:

1. the global scope
2. the function scope
3. the class body
4. the lambda scope

When creating a class statement, the class body is executed as a function would and the local namespace of that 'function' is used as the class attributes.

However, a class body is **not** a scope, and as such behaves differently from functions. In a function body, binding defines scope; assign to a name in a function and it is marked as a local. In a class, assigning to a name makes it a *global* until you actually do the assignment.

So your *first* `print()` call finds `my_str` as a global, because *later* in the class body you bind to the name. This is a consequence of class bodies not taking part in scopes.

Next, you define a lambda and call it. `my_str` is never assigned to in that lambda so it has to be found in a parent scope. Here the class body is not a scope, and the next scope up is the function scope. This is why that line prints `inside func`.

Last, you assign to the local name `my_str` in the class body, and print that local.

The moment you remove the assignment, the names in the class are treated as non-local; the first and last `print()` statements are now equal, and the name is simply looked up according to the normal scoping rules.

Comment: Could you extend your answer to explain the variation of Edit1 ?

Comment: @PabloGalindoSalgado: your edit only *confirms* that the post is a dupe.

Comment: I'm so sorry, then. I read the answers twice and do not understand that variation....but is straightforward as you said. Time for coffee. :(

Comment: @PabloGalindoSalgado: The answer there states: *If a name is assigned to within a class body*, almost at the start. You assigned to `my_str`, making it the same case as `y` there. Commenting out that line means you are no longer assigning to `my_str`, making it the same case as `x`.

Comment: Today I am not being careful enoght. My apologies and sorry for the confusion.