# Var scope Python

Tags: php, python

In python is every variable defined as a global scope? Can someone explain variable scope for python with the following example?  This is for python 2.7 but I wouldn't mind a python 3 explanation

**Python**

```
test = [1,2,3]

print test

def fun():
    print test

fun()
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3] 
[1, 2, 3]
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$test = [1,2,3];

var_dump($test);


function fun()
{
   var_dump($test); 
}

fun();
?>
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
}
NULL
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: test in /home/coderpad/solution.php on line 10
```

**EDIT** Saw this post [Python class scoping rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29333359/python-class-scoping-rules)  but I am still confused.

Comment: theres a lot of info in that link you posted so maybe clarifying what is still confusing you?

Comment: `$test` is not declared as a global this in the `fun()` scope you can't access it, call `fun($test);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined a global variable `test` in Python and global variables are accessible in functions. To achieve the same effect in PHP, you would have to write:

```
<?php

$test = [1,2,3];

var_dump($test);


function fun()
{
   global $test; // <---- add this
   var_dump($test); 
}

fun();
```

to achieve the same effect. You can find more information about Python variable scope [here](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/python-variable-scope-notes/).

Comment: This makes a lot of sense and thank you for the link