# Nested Class vs. Scope

Tags: python, scope

I'm new to programming. First, the following is my code:

```
x = 11

def f():
    x = 22
    print(x)
    class C:
        print(x)

f()
```

I got three printed results, "22 22", as output. When I changed my code like this:

```
x = 11

def f():
    x = 22
    print(x)
    class C:
        print(x)
        x = 33
        print(x)

f()
```

I got "22 11 33" instead of what I'm expecting: "22 22 33".

It seems like when I add a local `x` in the nested class, the order of variable searching is changed. I believe there's some tricks about scopes that I don't know yet. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: @Barmar From my reading it doesn't look like this case is covered in that question.

Comment: @thebjorn I'm having trouble finding anything about classes nested in functions. When I google for info about nested classes, it's all about classes nested in other classes.

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296677/creating-a-class-within-a-function-and-access-a-function-defined-in-the-containi) may be more helpful

Comment: @Barmar if you go to the last answer and end up at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246523/how-references-to-variables-are-resolved-in-python you should be set :-)