# How can I create classes with different class attributes within a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to have a function that allows generating classes with custom class attributes. Like so:

```
def test_factory(a):
    class Test:
        a = a
    return Test
```

However, when I try to call `test_factory`, I get an error:

```
test_factory(1)
> NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

The expected behaviour would be:

```
t1 = test_factory(1)
t2 = test_factory(2)
print(t1.a, t2.a)
> 1, 2
```

How can I create classes that differ in their class attributes by calling a function?

Comment: Seems like you're coming from JS. More pythonic way would be to use a dictionary

Comment: there is this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296677/creating-a-class-within-a-function-and-access-a-function-defined-in-the-containi) I found. It might be worth a read

Comment: Note that you would get a similar error if ``Test`` were a function instead of a class. [Name resolution rules](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names) in Python cause every assignment to imply the variable is local to that block.

Comment: @MaxxikCZ thanks - that link indeed was worth a read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When parsing the `class` statement, the assignment to `a` defines it as part of the temporary class namespace, similar to an assignment to a local variable in a function definition. As such, the name `a` then shadows the name of the parameter in the enclosing function scope.

You can either change the parameter name (as shown [by schwobaseggl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61460418/1126841))

```
def test_factory(a_value):
    class Test:
        a = a_value
    return Test
```

or set the attribute after the definition:

```
def test_factory(a):
    class Test:
        pass
    Test.a = a
    return Test
```

or call `type` directly:

```
def test_factory(a):
    return type('Test', (), {'a': a})
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to rename the function argument to not collide with the name of the class attribute:

```
def test_factory(b):
    class Test:
        a = b
    return Test

>>> t1 = test_factory(1)
>>> t2 = test_factory(2)
>>> print(t1.a, t2.a)
1 2
```