# Using a string variable as a variable name

Tags: python

I have a variable with a string assigned to it and I want to define a new variable based on that string.

```
foo = "bar"
foo = "something else"   
# What I actually want is:    
bar = "something else"
```

Comment: You probably DON'T want that. Why are you trying to do it?

Comment: No you don't. The reason you have to use `exec` is because `locals()` doesn't support modifications. `locals()` doesn't support modifications because it would make the implementation more complex and slower and is **never** a good idea

Comment: Similar Post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python

Comment: I landed on this post trying to find out how to assign instance variables for a class using a dictionary. If anybody else has the same problem, you can find a clean solution without exec here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187082/how-can-you-set-class-attributes-from-variable-arguments-kwargs-in-python

Answer (score 291):

You can use `exec` for that:

```
>>> foo = "bar"
>>> exec(foo + " = 'something else'")
>>> print bar
something else
>>>
```

Comment: +1 because he answered the question (as bad an idea as it may be).

Comment: @mgalgs why it's a bad idea? Any bad effect this solution have? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note use of `exec` / `eval` is [considered poor practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/9209546). I have not met a single use case where it has been helpful, and there are *usually* better alternatives such as `dict`.

Comment: why doesn't this work when used in pytest unittests?

Comment: +100 what @jpp said. While this answer is useful and correct, if you're writing something other than a one-off script, you can most likely use a `dict`.

Comment: @jpp It does, albeit much more niche than this. https://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/1/exec-in-python/

Comment: I found what seems like an optimal use case of exec() in turtle.py: setting all public class methods to work as global functions. If you have a better way of doing this that does not use exec(), please answer my question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66393376/is-it-possible-to-automatically-make-all-of-a-modules-public-class-methods-glob

Comment: doesn't work. wtf exec????

Comment: This is the best "direct" answer, but I think it should contain a claim indicating you might not want to follow it... (and linking to other answers)

Answer (score 177):

You will be much happier using a dictionary instead:

```
my_data = {}
foo = "hello"
my_data[foo] = "goodbye"
assert my_data["hello"] == "goodbye"
```

Comment: It does not seem to address the question.

Comment: Yes. This may be helpful, but it wasn't what the OP was asking.

Comment: I'm glad to see the answer is still here.  I think we can trust Stack Overflow readers to judge for themselves whether an answer suits their needs.  This answer does not provide "variable variables," it is true.  But I guarantee you that 99% of the people looking for them will be happier to have found dictionaries.

Comment: It does not DIRECTLY answer the question, however, people might be asking that question while ignoring they can use a dictionary for the same purpose

Comment: "I'm cold, how can I set my house on fire?"

Comment: I would argue it does answer the question. I think OP is asking for:

foo = "bar"
foo = "something else
print(bar)
-------------
output:
"Something else"

Comment: SO should let users vote to see how much a question is a case of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 125):

You can use `setattr`

```
name  = 'varname'
value = 'something'

setattr(self, name, value) #equivalent to: self.varname= 'something'

print (self.varname)
#will print 'something'
```

But, since you should inform an object to receive the new variable, this only works inside classes or modules.

Comment: Correct, it only works inside classes.

Comment: Can this be used inside Modules, so set a module-level attribute?  Eg. `MyModule.var`

Comment: To answer my own question, yes, it can be used from within a module, on itself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933470/how-do-i-call-setattr-on-the-current-module