# Map variables to dictionary values, and call with reference to key?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm trying to assign class variables at runtime based on key/value pairs in a dictionary, where the key is what is called, and the value refers to the variable to be set.

```
keys = {'hours':'hours', 'minutes':'minutes'}
hours = 0
minutes = 0

def set_time(self, key, value):
    self.keys[key] = value
```

`set_time`, will not be a simple setter, but will take `value` as a string and convert it to integer minutes or hours.  I want to look up the correct variable name based on the `key` parameter, but this code changes the value of the dictionary entry instead.  Tried to search google and SO, but don't know the words to describe what I'm trying to find.

Comment: You're probably looking for [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#setattr).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a string variable as a variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553721/using-a-string-variable-as-a-variable-name)

Comment: That is **not** how Python names work. I suggest you read [this](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using Python's setattr method?

For example,

```
setattr(x, 'minutes', 40)
```

is the same as writing

```
x.minutes = 40
```

Comment: That should be `setattr(x, 'minutes', 40)`.

Comment: Oops!  Forgot the quotes.  Thanks.