# How to access the string stored in the variable? (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, naming-conventions, variable-names

Since my last question was rather poorly worded, here is a different question that will provide me the same benefits!

First of all, I want to accomplish one thing: create a new `Set` and set that `Set's` name to the value of a variable (a string I would set it equal to, e.g. `new_set_name = 'buffalo'`)

I want it to be something like this `new_set_name = Set([])` Except I don't want the end result to be a `Set` with the name `new_set_name` I want the name of the `Set` to instead be: `buffalo`.

I tried quite hard to make this as non-confusing as possible, but if it is, let me know! I will try to fix it!

Comment: Do you mean you want to use the vaue of a variable as a variable name ? in that case I'd check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553721/using-a-string-variable-as-a-variable-name

Comment: Seconded: [use a dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a variable in the module namespace like so

```
new_set_name = 'buffalo'
globals()[new_set_name] = set()
```

Namespaces are implemented by `dict`s but python figures out context when you use the variables so you don't have to refer to them directly. You can view or update at other module namespaces using their `__dict__` variable but its more customary to use `setattr`

```
import os
print(os.__dict__)
os.__dict__[new_set_name] = set()
setattr(os, new_set_name, set())
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what you mean, but if you want to use a variable value as a variable name you need to use setattr inside a class like this

```
class Test:
   def testmethod(self,name):
      setattr(self,name,Set())
```

Then you can say

```
tmp = Test()
varname= 'buffalo'
tmp.testmethod(varname)
```

And you'll have

```
In [29]: type(t.buffalo)
Out[29]: sets.Set
```