# Can I use the value of a variable as a parameter name for a function?

Tags: python, parameters, expression, parameter-passing

There are a number of StackOverflow questions asking about using a variable as a variable (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553721/using-a-string-variable-as-a-variable-name), but I **don't think this is a duplicate** of those.  I want to know if I can use the value of a variable as a function parameter.

For example, let's say I want to call a function that will populate one of two different MySQL tables:

- The **name** table's columns are `id` and `fullname`.
- The **phone** table's columns are `id` and `phonenum`

```
data = get_data()                 # data = a full name or a phone number
data_type = get_data_type(data)   # data_type = "name" or "phone"
....
column_names_for_tables = {'name': 'fullname', 'phone': 'phonenum'}
column_name = column_names_for_tables[data_type]
# column_name now = "fullname" or "phonenum", depending on the value of #data

new_entry = MakeNewEntry(date=datetime.datetime.now(), id=123, <column_name>=data)
```

Of course that last line is not valid Python, but my goal is to dynamically generate the function call:

```
new_entry = MakeNewEntry(date=datetime.datetime.now(), id=123, fullname=data)
```

or

```
new_entry = MakeNewEntry(date=datetime.datetime.now(), id=123, phonenum=data)
```

That is, I want to use the value of `column_name`  as the name of my parameter.

Can I do that?

(For this example, please assume that `MakeNewEntry()` is not under my control - it will accept `date`, `id`, and a `phonenum` or `fullname` parameter, but can't be refactored.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [double star operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters) to pass in arbitrary arguments to a function:

```
col = 'foo'
val = 'bar'
kwargs = {col: bar}

some_function(**kwargs)
```

And you can make that shorter by inlining the dictionary like so:

```
some_function(**{col: var})
```

You can mix and match the syntax and end up with something like this:

```
MakeNewEntry(date=datetime.datetime.now(), id=123, **{column_name: data})
```