# Creating an object from a string, is it possible?

Tags: python

Is it possible to do the following

This works

```
usethismodule.LoginUsername="my value"
usethismodule.LoginPassword="another value"
```

But I don't know the second part of the object until the code is being run, I think what I want is this

```
listofthings=[]
listofthings.append('usethismodule.LoginUsername')
listofthings.append('usethismodule.LoginPassword')

for value in listofthings:
    value="A value I set"
```

This would have the same outcome as the above. Does that make sense?

Comment: You might want `setattr`, for example, `setattr(usethismodule, 'LoginUsename', "my value")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a string variable as a variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11553721/953482). Short answer: use a dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) and a dictionary would do the trick.

```
dictofthings = {
    'usethismodule.LoginUsername': 'my value',
    'usethismodule.LoginPassword': 'my other value'
}

for k in dictofthings:
    setattr(eval(k.split('.')[0]), k.split('.')[1], dictofthings[k])
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: But the module name is part of the data as well. You made it part of the code.

Comment: OK, changed. Note that eval *may* be a security hole, but `ast.literal_eval` won't work. Is this better?

Comment: I'd say it's better because that's what they apparently want, but worse because of that eval security issue :-). Maybe a mix of your answer and Austin's answer (which assumes a single module name) would be best.

Answer (score 0):

You keep saying `usethismodule.<something>`. So let's pretend you're right.

Python maintains a `dict` of currently imported modules in `sys.modules`. You can look up a module, by name, and get an "object". (A `module` object, in fact.)

If you have an object in hand, you can either hard-code an access to one of its attributes, or use `getattr` or `setattr` on it.

```
import sys

module_name = "usethismodule"   # I don't know where this come from.

utm = sys.modules[module_name]

utm.LoginUsername = "xyzzy"
utm.LoginPassword = "secret123"

# or

pw_attr_name = "passWord"       # Maybe you read this from a config file?
setattr(utm, pw_attr_name, "secret123")
```