# How to create an instance of a class for each value in a list?

Tags: python

For example, say I have a list:

```
people = ["bob", "tom", "joe"]
```

I'd like to make a class instance for each name.

I'm guessing there's no easy way to create variable names on the fly, like so:

```
for num in range(0, 3):
    person_"num" = Person(people[num])
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a string variable as a variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553721/using-a-string-variable-as-a-variable-name)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a list of `Person`s instead?

```
persons = []
people = [ "bob", "tom", "joe" ]
for p in people:
    persons.append(Person(p))
```

Then you can index them by number.

Comment: A more Pythonic way is to use list comprehension `persons = [Person(p) for p in people]`

Comment: Oh thanks, The error came from setting the object to person[0] without having defined that variable earlier.

Answer (score 2):

As recommended in the comments using a dictionary is good for this:

```
people = ["bob", "tom", "joe"]
person_lookup = {}
for p in people:
    person_lookup[p] = Person(p)
```

or more idiomatically:

```
people = ["bob", "tom", "joe"]
person_lookup = {p: Person(p) for p in people}
```

then use like:

```
person_lookup["bob"].some_method_on_person()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exec` to accomplish your goal.

```
for num in range(0, 3):
    exec("person_"+str(num)+" = Person(people[num])")
```

Comment: Why isn't it recommended?

Comment: @Dima esp. in cases where you are accepting user input, malicious activity can occur.

Comment: It's unnecessary (you can use indexed lists rather than named variables) and unsafe (if you do exec on user input, you could have potential security flaws)

Comment: Can you explain how to use indexed lists? This doesn't work: person[0] = Person("Joe")

Comment: `person[i] =...` won't work unless a list `person` has been already created with enough space for at least `i+1` items.