# Python Variable variable for directories in a folder

Tags: python, while-loop, directory

The title may sound confusing so here is what I want...

I have the following code:

```
import os
dir_list = os.walk('aFolder').next()[1]     #aFolder is the directory location

SizeOfList =  len(dir_list)
NumbOfList = 0

while (NumbOfList < SizeOfList):
    print dir_list [NumbOfList]
    NumbOfList = NumbOfList + 1
```

This code gets all the folders (not including subfolders) in the folder called 'aFolder' and shows them to the user. However, I want to store these folder names as different variables. The problem I have here is, I don't know the number of folders in this directory so I can't set 1 variable to `dir_list [0]` and another to `dir_list [1]` etcetera.

**I need this because I want to select and choose certain folders with an `if` statement. If you have an alternative to doing this than mine, I will happily accept it.**

My solution to this was using a while loop. However, I can't figure out how to change the variable name each time the while loop repeats. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553721/using-a-string-variable-as-a-variable-name) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-via-a-while-loop). The third link was the closest, but I still can't figure out how to implement it.

Thank you in advance to anyone who helps.

Comment: Aren't you already storing them, in `dir_list`?

Comment: @kabanus yes there is already a list. The first line after the import does that.

Comment: Why is the list not sufficient? Why do you need to create separate variables? This is just a bad idea from the start.

Comment: That's what I'm asking, why is the list variable not counting here as a variable...? You can access directory names easily afterwards.

Comment: I would like them as separate variables so that I can pick with an `if` statement and select a certain directory.

Comment: Than write **that** in your question. Write exactly what you need afterwards. This is an [xy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Ok will change now.

Comment: maybe you can use a dictionary, if you want to store some additional data for each folder. Like d=dict()......d.update({dir_list [NumbOfList] : data})

Comment: @dede could you expand. it sounds like the thing I would like.

Comment: even if you can (which you can, but it is really not recommended) get var0, var1, ... var42 as your folder names, what are you going to do with them?

Comment: Suppose you created the variables... how would you know which ones to use later in your program? This looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Do not create dynamic variables, *use a container like a list or dictionary*.

Comment: Also, use `dir_list =  [f.name for f in os.scandir('aFolder') if f.is_dir()]`, don't do what you are doing with `os.walk`. And `NumbOfList` is just `len(dir_list)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga why is there something wrong with `os.walk`?

Comment: No, but it is meant for walking a directory tree, not getting the second element of the tuple returned by the first iteration. It's a huge waste, and hard to understand what you are trying to do when you read the code.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `os.scandir` comes up with an error that module has no attribute scandir.

Comment: @SankarshMakam is there any reason you are using Python2 instead of Python 3?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga no, just I can't find my python 3's editing shell/ IDLE.

Comment: @SankarshMakam you should use Python 3. Python 2 is at it's end of life in 2020.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Why what will happen?

Comment: It will no longer officially be supported. It will be like Windows XP. There are only two good reasons to use Python 2 over 3: your boss is making you, or you have a codebase already written in Python 2. If you are learning to program right now, learn 3, not 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked me to expand my comment. Here it is:

```
import os

d=dict()
dir_list = os.walk('/tmp').next()[1]

for idx in range(len(dir_list)):
  d.update({dir_list[idx]: idx})

for k, v in d.items():
  print "k=", k, "v=", v
  d.update({k: v+1})  # to update the variable
  print "new value of <%s>"%(k), d[k]
  print
```

Comment: I must be missing something right in front of me, but what is k and v?

Comment: k and v are "key" and "value" of the dictionary. Each key has its value. The key is your variable name and value is its individual value.

Comment: Is the value random?

Comment: sure not :-)   you have to set it. It can be anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see if a string is a substring of a folder in your list:

```
for directory in dir_list:
     #Do stuff for everyone
     if "mysubstring" in directory:
         dospecialstuff()
```

Comment: Yes, this works... It's just I wanted to see if part of `myname` was in part of any of the list. So as in it would recognise `Hwqdmyname23`.

Comment: @SankarshMakam I'm not sure I understood, is this the solution? Just write in your code exactly what you're going to do - write the code assuming you have var1, var2 etc..

Comment: No. I want the `if` statement to recognize folder names with `myname` in it. It doesn't necessarily have to be called `myname`.

Comment: @SankarshMakam I see now, I'll show a simple (though not optimal solution).

Comment: @SankarshMakam Please use common sense, that's obviously a typo. fixed.

Comment: @SankarshMakam Please next time try to be clear with your questions - for your own benefit. Also, do not forget to accept an answer once you're satisfied - for the benefit of future googlers.