# Convert string to char in python

Tags: python, string-conversion

Is there a possibility (e.g. a built-in function) to convert a string to a char in python? For example, if I assign a value to the variable

```
p1=100
```

and then have the string

```
"p1",
```

is it possible to assign the value of p1 to a new variable t like

```
t=char("p1")
```

so that I get

```
print(t)->100 ?
```

Obviously, above mentioned solution does not work as it throws following error message:

```
NameError: name 'char' is not defined
```

Edit: The question is not about best practices: I know that I should do this with a dictionary, but what I am trying to do is to understand data types in Python and how to convert them. Convert a string to an integer is fairly easy, for example, so I was wondering if the same applies to string to char conversions. 
The eval() command does solve the example's question, but it does not answer above mentioned problem. So I would edit the goal to

```
 char("p11")=20
```

which should give me

```
 print(p11) -> 20
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Are you possibly looking for `chr()`?

Comment: I tried, but it gives me another error message: TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Comment: `t = eval('p1')`. But please think of alternative, like the suggested answer below.

Comment: You want "string to char conversion", but there is no `char` datatype in Python.

Comment: I suggest that you start from reading a Python tutorial. It's an excellent way to familiarize yourself with the language, not typing random bits of code and asking on Stackoverflow why they doesn't work.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553721/using-a-string-variable-as-a-variable-name, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for `eval()`: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#eval

```
p1 = 100
print(eval('p1'))   # prints 100
```

If you want to evaluate expressions you can also use `exec()`

```
p1 = 100
t = 'p1 += 99'
exec(t)
print(p1)           # prints 199
```

But as other already pointed out, you should avoid it if possible.
timgeb provided a nice alternative with dictionaries for example.

---

If you want to turn a string into a **global** variable you could also do:

```
globals()['y'] = 5
print(y)
```

Note: when you run your code in a global scope (outside a function), you can also use `locals()['y'] = 5` - **but** this will not work in a non-global scope!

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Could you please elaborate on why it is so bad?

Comment: ``eval()`` could also run malicious code. If you're working with user input, this could be a security risk.

Comment: So if I gather correctly, it does not change the string to a char, but executes the string. That means that if I put  eval('p1')=20, it throws following error message: SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Comment: You keep asking for "changing a string to a char", but that does not make sense. If ``eval()`` does not meet your needs you can also try ``exec()`` where you can also work with assignments - I have updated my answer to demonstrate ``exec()``

Comment: I'm still super confused what OP means by "char".

Comment: What I mean is that I want to convert a string into a variable name.

Comment: The exec() command, as well as the eval() command, do not convert a string to a variable name, but run the string as python code, as I understand it now.

Comment: ``exec`` can create a new variable from a string with an assignment. The following will work, even if you did not define ``x`` prior to executing the code: ``exec('x=100') -> print(x) -> prints 100``. *However* ``exec("x") = 1`` will not work, for the same reasons ``eval("x") = 1`` does not work.

Comment: So the answer is that it is impossible to directly convert a string to a variable name?

Comment: There is one ... when working with global variables. Give me a sec, I will update the answer once again ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help mpf82. (I know that expressions of gratitude are frowned upon on this website, but since I already got 4 down-votes, I guess I have nothing to lose anymore ...;)

Answer (score 3):

No. Use a dictionary.

```
>>> names = {'p1': 100, 'p2': 200}
>>> t = names['p1']
>>> t
100
```

This will throw a `KeyError` if the name does not exist:

```
>>> t = names['p3']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'p3'
```

... but you can use `dict.get` and provide a default value:

```
>>> t = names.get('p3', 'default')
>>> t
'default'
```

where the default-default-value is `None`.

(By the way, this has nothing to do with converting strings to a char(acter?), your terminology is quite confusing.)

Comment: Yes. It's a bad practice to call directly, too risky.

A question was already made into Stack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553721/using-a-string-variable-as-a-variable-name

Comment: That's the best solution imo. There's also the get() method `names.get('p1')`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change it into character then do not use "`char`"
in python the char is declared as `chr`
so you can go like:

```
chr(input('Enter here'))
```