# How to use element of list as object for a class?

Tags: python

So i have this class

```
class Character(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.NAME = ''
        self.life = 50
```

I also have this list

```
 players = ["red","green","blue","yellow"]
```

I'm trying to make each "player" become a Character and this is what I did

```
for player in players:
    player = Character()
```

Now when i go

```
print(red.life)    #or if i try
print("red".life)    #why doesn't it work?
# for some reason it uses player as object for the
# class but I want the element of the list to be used!
```

Comment: What do you believe the line `print("red".life)` does?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a string variable as a variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553721/using-a-string-variable-as-a-variable-name)

Comment: You need to pass each element of the list as an argument to `__init__`; the string `"red"` is not, and cannot be, an instance of `Character`. `players = [Character(color) for color in ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"]`.

Comment: I thought strings could be used as variable for object instances so I thought `print("red".life)` would have given me player red's life! @Greg Hilston

Comment: Understood. That's what is actually happening. You're asking the string "red" to provide you with the property life, which it doesn't have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would work by putting players into a dict:

```
class Character(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.NAME = ''
        self.life = 50

players = ["red","green","blue","yellow"]
dict_players = {}

for player in players:
    dict_players[player] = Character()
```

However, printing would only work if you create a `__str__` method for your class.

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of strings, and `"red".life` is attempting to call a member variable `life`, which string objects do not contain. Instead, create separate class instances:

```
class Character(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.NAME = ''
      self.life = 50

red = Character()
green = Character()
...
```

Then, you can call `life`:

```
print(red.life)
```

Comment: I don't want to do that because I don't know how many players will be playing, with the list if someone isn't playing I can just remove him from the list.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
for player in players:
    player = Character()
```

will create a new `Character` instance for each item in `players` (not using the item itself) and assign it to the `player` variable (each time ovverridding the previous assignment). This won't of course change anything to your `players` list. After the loop is terminated, you get one single `Character()` instance bound to the `player` variable, and that's all. IOW, you'd get the same practical result replacing the loop with a single:

```
player = Character()
```

but it won't obviously be of any use.

> print(red.life)

Where have you defined a variable named `red` ?

> or if i try
>   print("red".life)

`"red"` is a string. A string has no attribute `life`.

> for some reason it uses player as object for the
>   class but I want the element of the list to be used!

The "elements of the list" (I assume you mean the `players` list) are strings too. If you want to get a list of `Character` instances instead, you can get it that what:

```
class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.life = 50

playernames = ["red", "green", "blue", "42"]
players = [Character(name) for name in playernames]
```

but that will still not create any variables named `red`, `green` etc, just a list of Character instances.

If you want to be able to retrieve specific Character instances, you will either need to explicitly  create variables or use a dict. Creating variables:

```
red = Character("red")
yellow = Character("yellow")
# etc
```

but this means all your characters are hardcoded - you cannot have more or less players nor name them differently etc.

Using a dict:

```
playernames = ["red", "green", "blue", "42"]
players = {name:Character(name) for name in playernames}

print(players["red"].life)
print(players["green"].life)
# etc
```

Comment: Is there no way of turning a string into a "soon to be variable?" I tried using eval(player) = Character() why didn't it work?

Comment: eval doesn't work that way - but anyway if you don't know beforehand how many players you have using a dict is the only sane solution. How would you know which variables have been defined else?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I tried to understand all of your answers and made it work, It's for a game I'm trying to make and it's my first time doing something so complicated, my coding is a mess and it has 0 readability. For now I have only made this character creator and world map creator, the map is made of various tiles I will give names to (like shop, river, jungle), each name will have special properties. I have made it possible for the characters to spawn and move around and I will now make something that figures out on what type of tile the Character is, sadly I'm having a hard time figuring out how to give every tile different coordinates.
I'm very grateful.