# Change variable values with similar names in function

Tags: python

I have different valued variables not in an array; e.g.

```
a = "united states"
b = "canada" 
c = "mexico"
```

I also have similarly named variables with the same suffix

```
a_pop = 0
b_pop = 0
c_pop = 0
```

I have made a function to select randomly `a`, `b` or `c`, but is there any way to edit the value of {`selected value}_pop` (if `a` then edit `a_pop`'s value, `b` to `b_pop` etc.) in a function without changing the previous variables of or using an tedious if/else ladder?

For example, `a` is selected. Now (with `a` selected) I want to add `1` to `a_pop`'s value.

Comment: Short answer: you really don't want to do that, use a dict instead.

Comment: Also: [Using a string variable as a variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553721/using-a-string-variable-as-a-variable-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little different from your original code, but more Pythonic:

```
names = {
    'a' : "united states"
    'b' : "canada" 
    'c' : "mexico"
}

values = {
    'a' : 0
    'b' : 0
    'c' : 0
}
```

Picking a random variable `var`...

```
values[var] += 1
```

Hope it's clear how this works for your needs. If not feel free to ask for clarification.