# How to check DataSeries for continuity?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame named `df` with column named 'step', which is just an incremental counter (1,2,3,4,etc):

```
step col1 col2
1    2    3
2    3    5
3    1    0
4    8    9
5    2    3
```

I'm selecting from `df` some rows of interest:

```
    work_df = df[df[col1] < df[col2]]

step col1 col2
1    2    3
2    3    5
4    8    9
5    2    3
```

Now I should split `work_df` to some sub_df's by continuity of 'step' (i.e. if `work_df['step'] == [1,2,3,7,8,9]` then `[1,2,3]` belongs to `sub_df_1` while `[7,8,9]` belongs to `sub_df_2` etc.), currently I'm doing it this way:

```
        for idx, row in work_df.iterrows():
            if row['step'] > prev_step + 1:
                if step_count > 1: #don't want to have df with only 1 row
                    interval_list.append({'step_count': step_count ... })
                step_count = 0
            else:
                step_count += 1
            prev_step = row['step']
```

I'm building new sub_df's then based on information from `interval_list`. But I'm not sure this is the best way to achieve what I really need:

```
sub_df1=
step col1 col2
1    2    3
2    3    5

sub_df2=
step col1 col2
4    8    9
5    2    3
```

Are there better ways to split DataFrame by continuity of a column?

Comment: please provide sample data as well as expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can here group by `(df[col] != df[col].shift(1)+1).cumsum()`, or as [@MarkWang says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57539975/how-to-check-dataseries-for-continuity/57540017?noredirect=1#comment101544255_57540017) `df['data'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()`. Indeed, if we use your sample data:

```
>>> df
   data
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     7
4     8
5     9
```

then this expression will yield:

```
>>> df['data'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
Name: data, dtype: int64
```

So we can here perform a `groupby` on these values:

```
>>> list(df.groupby(df['data'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()))
[(1,    data
0     1
1     2
2     3), (2,    data
3     7
4     8
5     9)]
```

We thus here have two groups: `[1,2,3]` and `[7,8,9]`. You thus can here obtain your two groups with:

```
>>> (__, sub_df_1), (__, sub_df_2) = df.groupby(df['data'].diff().ne(1).cumsum())
>>> sub_df_1
   data
0     1
1     2
2     3
>>> sub_df_2
   data
3     7
4     8
5     9
```

or for the second sample data fragment you provided:

```
>>> (__, sub_df1), (__, sub_df2) = df2.groupby(df2['data'].diff().ne(1).cumsum())
>>> sub_df1
   step  col1  col2
0     1     2     3
1     2     3     5
>>> sub_df2
   step  col1  col2
2     4     8     9
3     5     2     3
```

You can here for example use list comprehension, or an `itemgetter` to obtain the corresponding groups. For example:

```
>>> [g[1] for g in df2.groupby(df2['step'].diff().ne(1).cumsum())]
[   step  col1  col2
0     1     2     3
1     2     3     5,    step  col1  col2
2     4     8     9
3     5     2     3]
```

You can drop groups of length with `1` as well:

```
>>> [g[1] for g in df2.groupby(df2['step'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()) if len(g[1]) > 1]
[   step  col1  col2
0     1     2     3
1     2     3     5,    step  col1  col2
2     4     8     9
3     5     2     3]
```

This list thus contains the two subgroups. I strongly advice against *assign by name*. Yes it is [strictly speaking possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11553721/67579). But it is an anti-pattern, and it usually does more harm than good.

Comment: `cumsum` over boolean is always a nice way to create groups:)

Comment: @MarkWang: yes, I was quite amused when I first discovered this trick :)

Comment: Though I would write something like `df['data'].diff().ne(1)` to generate boolean

Comment: Thank you very much but it's a bit complicated for Pandas newbie like me. As a fact I could get any number of sub_df's, so I guess there should be something like a loop somewhere?

Comment: @user3523475: you can use `from operator import itemgetter`, and then `list(map(itemgetter(1)), df2.groupby(df2['data'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()))` to obtain a list of all your subgroups.