# How to call a variable in the name of a new variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am relatively new to Python, and I'm wondering how I can call a variable in the name of a new variable.

For example, when I have the 2 following variables and their values:

```
number1 = 100
string1 = 'abc'
```

and I want to write a line of code such that I can create new variables who's name contains the values of variables number1 and string1 (e.g new_var_100 and new_var_abc)

For example:

```
new_var_(value_of_number1) = 200   ##What to write on LHS?
new_var_(value_of_string1) = 'def'  ##What to write on LHS?
```

such that when I call new_var_100, it returns 200; and when I call new_var_abc, it returns 'def'.

Thanks very much.

Comment: you don't want to do this. make a dictionary instead.

Comment: For a number, in this case, multiply by 2.
For a string, increase the "value" of each character by 3 or the length of the string, your choice.

Comment: You should probably use a dictionary, but if you really want to do this, check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553721/using-a-string-variable-as-a-variable-name

Answer (score 0):

not realy sure if you shuld do this but here goes:

````
string1 = 'abc'

globals()[f"string1{number1}]=200```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can't - at least not without involving some very hacky solutions.

If you want to treat variable names as strings, modifying or concatenating them, you actually want a dictionary:

```
my_dict = {'number1' = 100, 'string1' = 'abc'}
```

You then access those values by passing the key values inside brackets - which fundamentally work like arbitrary variable names:

```
my_dict['number1']  # returns 100 
my_dict['string1']  # returns 'abc'
```

you can then use a simple for loop to create new values based on some logic:

```
for value in my_dict.values():
    my_dict['new_var_' + str(value)] = 200
```

Note that my code simply sets the values associated with the keys `'new_var_100'` and `'new_var_abc'` to 200. You'll need extra logic if you want to update strings and ints differently.