# For loop with f-string with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, f-string

I need to try create two loops (must be separate):

LOOP 1) for each fruit:

1. keep rows if that fruit is True
2. remove rows with duplicate dates (either row can be deleted)
3. save the result of the above as a dataframe for each fruit

LOOP 2) for each dataframe created, graph date on fruit_score:

```
    concat   apple_score  banana_score       date        apple      banana  
1   apple     0.400         0.400        2010-02-12      True        False  
2   banana    0.530         0.300        2010-01-12      False       True   
3   kiwi      0.532          0.200       2010-03-03      False       False  
4   bana      0.634         0.100        2010-03-03      False       True
```

I tried:

```py
fruits = ['apple',  'banana',   'orange']
for fruit in fruits:
    selected_rows = df[df[ fruit ] == True ]
    df_f'{fruit}' = selected_rows.drop_duplicates(subset='date')

for fruit in fruits:
    df_f'{fruit}'.plot(x="date", y=(f'{fruit}_score'), kind="line")
```

Comment: Are you trying to programatically define the name of a variable ? you're expecting to get a variable called df_apple for example ?

Comment: You could use a dict instead of getting a variable name based on the for loop: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11553769/1735729

Comment: Not variables but I was hoping to generate 2 dataframes labelled df_apple and df_banana (in this example)

Comment: try `isin`  and drop dupes `df[df['concat'].isin(fruits)].drop_duplicates(subset=['date'],keep='first)`

Comment: Use a dict then, `fruits_df = {}` and in your for loop use `fruits_df[fruit] = ...`

Comment: also don't use for loops in pandas, it should be a last resort when you can't use any other methods.

Comment: @Manakin i dont think that will work cause he got "bana" in concat but the column banana is set to true. + he wishes to drop duplicated by date between same fruit, the other one will drop duplicated for all fruits that have same date. Hes not looping on dataframe, but on fruits.

Comment: @Youyoun you can subset on more than one column, just add `fruits` to `.drop_duplicates` nothing complex here, no need to iterate over the list either.

Comment: @Manakin How would you create `df_apple` and `df_banana` without looping over the `fruits` list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do something along the lines suggested by @youyoun:

```
dfs = {}
fruits = ['apple',  'banana']
for fruit in fruits:
    selected_rows = df[df[ fruit ] == True ].drop_duplicates(subset='date')
    dfs[f'df_{fruit}'] = selected_rows

for a,v in dfs.items():
    print(a)
    print(v)
```

Output:

```
df_apple
  concat  apple_score  banana_score        date  apple  banana
1  apple          0.4           0.4  2010-02-12   True   False
df_banana
   concat  apple_score  banana_score        date  apple  banana
2  banana        0.530           0.3  2010-01-12  False    True
4    bana        0.634           0.1  2010-03-03  False    True
```

Comment: even simplier you could do `dfs = {fruit, data for fruit,data in df.groupby('fruit').unique()}`  or something along those lines.