# How can I use items from list as variable and assign values to it?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read multiple csv files using pandas library and I want to assign that dataframe to items in the list using for loop.
Currently I have two lists (One list contains dataframe names and second list contains dataframe)
I am using below code for example:

```
list1 = ['amol', 'ankit', 'akshay', 'ashok'] # in actual there are 100+ items in the list
marks = [50, 60, 70, 80]   # marks list actully contains dataframe - pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

for ind, name in enumerate(list1):
    name = marks[ind]
print(amol)

# NameError: name 'amol' is not defined.
```

This is not assigning value to 'amol' and giving "NameError: name 'amol' is not defined."

I tried using dictionary.

```
list1 = ['amol', 'ankit', 'akshay', 'ashok']
marks = [50, 60, 70, 80]

mark_dict = {}

for ind, name in enumerate(list1):
    mark_dict[name] = marks[ind] 
print(mark_dict['amol'])
```

Dictionary is working but I want to assign value to 'amol' so below code can be executed and shold give me a output (in actual project it should return dataframe).
Please advice how can I do it?

```
print(amol)
```

Comment: *"I can't use dictionary in my project"* - why not? Most of Python is dictionaries under the hood, so if that's true you may have a huge problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a string variable as a variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553721/using-a-string-variable-as-a-variable-name)

Comment: Can you include what you expect `amol` to be?

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do here, you might want to try [`zip(list1, marks)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: You'r printing a variable that you are not created,

Comment: If you don't want use dic, thats alright, But try to add some sample output

Comment: U could create a list of tupele like `[(name, mark), (name, mark), (name, mark).....]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add variables to the module's global namespace using `globals()`. `zip` will turn the two lists into an itertator of matching tuples `(list1[0], marks[0])` etc... `globals().update` works like a regular `dict.update` so these tuples can be fed into it directly to update the namespace.

```
list1 = ['amol', 'ankit', 'akshay', 'ashok'] # in actual there are 100+ items in the list
marks = [50, 60, 70, 80]

globals().update(zip(list1, marks))
print(amol)
```

This is not a common thing to do. Normally one would keep dynamically generated data like this in a dictionary.

Comment: I want to read multiple csv files using pandas library and I want to assign that dataframe to 'amol' using for loop. so when I print amol it should print dataframe.