# How to create a Thread variable while program is working?

Tags: python, string, multithreading, dictionary

I want to create new **Threads** while the program is running. I mean, instead of doing like this:

```
from threading import Thread

# new thread
t1 = Thread(target=someFunc)
t1.join()
```

I want to do like this:

```
from threading import Thread

# get input
tname = input('What do you want to call your Thread?') # Let's say 'super'

# The 'super' name here came from input, and 'super' must be a variable.
# The goal is to take the Thread name with input instead of changing the source and create a multiple Threads.

super = Thread(target= someFunc)
super.start()
```

Is there any way to do this? I tried to do it using a dictionary but I couldn't do it well.

Here's what I try:

```
import sys
import re
import time
import threading

while True:

    # Get input from user
    tname = input("What do you want to call your Thread?\n")


    # Get thread name using re
    def getThreadName(getName=''):

        global threadname
        threadname = getName

        # Create thread giving it a name
        try:
            threadname = re.search(r'create (.*)', tname)
            if threadname:
                threadname = list(map(str, threadname.groups()))
                threadname = ''.join(threadname)
                print("THREAD NAME:", threadname)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print("Sorry, something went wrong.")
            sys.exit()


    # Get Thread name using re
    getThreadName(tname)


    # Target func
    def targetfunc():

        global threadname
        
        while True:
            print(f"I'm the {threadname} Thread!\n")
            time.sleep(5)


    # Global vars
    global threadname
    global names

    # Create dict
    names = dict()

    # add new thread and start
    names[threadname] = threading.Thread(target = targetfunc)
    names[threadname].start()

    # Inside the dict
    print("INSIDE THE DICT:", names)
```

In this code, to create **Threads**, you must use an input like `create (threadname)`.

As I said above, ***The goal is to take the Thread name with input instead of changing the source and create a multiple Threads.***

How to achieve this solution? Hope you help.

Comment: `super` is the name of a Python built-in class. Don't use it as a variable name.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I just want to give an example. It can be whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have not implemented the string processing. But if I have understood you correctly this should get you going. Please execute the code and let me know if you have gotten your answer or, anything else is required.

```
import threading
from time import sleep

def workerFunction(threadName):
    while True:
        print("I'm the {} Thread".format(threadName))
        sleep(5)

def startCreating():
    while True:
        tname = str(input("Enter thread name: "))
        thread = threading.Thread(target=workerFunction, args=(tname,))
        thread.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    startCreating()
```

Comment: Input must change the name of variable. Here, you're setting a parameter to function and printing what you wrote. I don't want this. I want to directly change the `thread` variable's name using input. I mean, you wrote `thread.start()` right? I want to change it's name using input. Such as `apple.start()`

Comment: In that case you can try following this answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/11553741/5830339 although it works with variables, it doesn't seem to work with class definition. I tried doing it like this `threadDef = "{} = threading.Thread(target=workerFunction, args=({},))".format(threadName, threadName)` and then `exec(threadDef)` . Doesn't seem to work. If you find a solution do post.