# How to name a variable using another variable?

Tags: python, naming-conventions, naming

I want to name a variable in python using the name of an existing variable. For example:

```
s = "Hello World"
words = s.split()
numofwords = len(words)
word(numofwords) = words[numofwords-1]
```

I'm not sure what syntax I would use to define the variable in line 4. What my code would hopefully do is print the last word in the string, stored as the variable wordx, x being the number of the last word. (In this case it would be 2.)I'm new to Python so there are probably some mistakes in the code.

Comment: This can be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553721/using-a-string-variable-as-a-variable-name

Comment: There definitely are a number of mistakes in the code but my suggestion to you is to really stop this train of thought before it goes further. Herein lies pain

Comment: Note that ``words`` already provides what you desire – it has a well-known name and provides access to individual items. You merely write ``words[1]`` instead of ``words2``.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionery:

```py
s = "Hello World"
words = s.split()
numofwords = len(words)
varname = "word" + str(numofwords)
vars = dict()
vars[varname] = words[numofwords-1]
```

and then you can access it like this:

```py
print(vars[varname])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary instead:

```
s = "Hello World"
words = s.split()
numofwords = len(words)
myVar = "word"+str(numofwords)
myVars = {}
myVars[myVar] = words[numofwords-1]
```

And get it using:

```
myVars[myVar]
```

To print:

```
print(myVars[myVar])
```