# Create variable whose name is the contents of a string held in another variable

Tags: python

I loop through the list of all 32 NFL teams and  through each iteration the team name is held in `team`. I am trying to create a `Team()` object referenced by the team name for each team. The first iteration `team = 'arizona_cardinals'`.

```
for team in teams:
 # I am looking for a way to say 'arizona_cardinals = Team()'
 team.text = Team() # something like this but this is obviously wrong
```

Comment: This is almost always a **bad** idea.  Use a dictionary, with the team name as the key.

Comment: One way might be to use an object with keys as team names? Then you can do `teams[team] = Team()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a string variable as a variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553721/using-a-string-variable-as-a-variable-name)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to make a dict with the team names as the key:

```py
team_dict = {team:Team() for team in teams}
```