# Function to assign input values to variables in python 3

Tags: python

Defining a **FUNCTION** through which we pass a variable name and in return we get a new variable assigned with a `user_inp` value.

**I Tried this :**

```
def Uinp(variable):
    variable = eval(input(f'Enter {variable} value : '))
    return variable

#trying the function.
x.Uinp

#trying to call the function.
Uinp(x)

print(x)
```

But coudn't get the desired results..

Comment: please add more information. I believe 'x' is a class so move this function to its class and then you can access it. Pass the returned value to class variable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a string variable as a variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553721/using-a-string-variable-as-a-variable-name)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

```
def Uinp(variable):
    variable = eval(input(f'Enter {variable} value : '))
    return variable

print(Uinp(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

So it's worth knowing that you *really should not do this*. It is very unexpected and modification of the globals dict is going to lead to some very hard to debug errors for you or someone else.

**HOWEVER**, it's definitely possible. Modification of the `globals` dict is legal Python.

```py
def my_function(var_name):
    """Please don't use this function it's actually Pandora's Box of bugs."""
    user_inp = input("Enter some value: ")
    globals()[var_name] = user_inp
```

Use it with:

```
>>> my_function("this_is_a_new_variable")
Enter some value: this is my value that I've entered

>>> print(this_is_a_new_variable)
this is my value that I've entered
```