# Is it possible to automatically make all of a module's public class methods global functions without exec()? turtle.py as an example

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, global, python-turtle

I've seen it claimed that `exec()` is never necessary and should always be avoided. While there are clearly better ways to do things 99.9% of the time, I was looking at turtle.py and found this:

```
## The following mechanism makes all methods of RawTurtle and Turtle available
## as functions. So we can enhance, change, add, delete methods to these
## classes and do not need to change anything here.

__func_body = """\
def {name}{paramslist}:
    if {obj} is None:
        if not TurtleScreen._RUNNING:
            TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True
            raise Terminator
        {obj} = {init}
    try:
        return {obj}.{name}{argslist}
    except TK.TclError:
        if not TurtleScreen._RUNNING:
            TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True
            raise Terminator
        raise
"""

def _make_global_funcs(functions, cls, obj, init, docrevise):
    for methodname in functions:
        method = getattr(cls, methodname)
        pl1, pl2 = getmethparlist(method)
        if pl1 == "":
            print(">>>>>>", pl1, pl2)
            continue
        defstr = __func_body.format(obj=obj, init=init, name=methodname,
                                    paramslist=pl1, argslist=pl2)
        exec(defstr, globals())
        globals()[methodname].__doc__ = docrevise(method.__doc__)

_make_global_funcs(_tg_screen_functions, _Screen,
                   'Turtle._screen', 'Screen()', _screen_docrevise)
_make_global_funcs(_tg_turtle_functions, Turtle,
                   'Turtle._pen', 'Turtle()', _turtle_docrevise)
```

This code is why using the turtle module is so convenient for beginners. In addition to Turtle class instances automatically assigning themselves Screens as necessary, this "mechanism" automatically makes every public class method into a global function. This is why code like this, which never directly instantiates any turtle classes, works:

```
import turtle
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.mainloop()
```

This will instantiate a Screen, instantiate a Turtle, assign the Screen to the Turtle, call a method of that Turtle instance to draw a line, and call a method of that Screen to keep the window open, all with automatically generated global functions. This is the best use case for exec() I've ever seen.

Is there a way to do this more pythonically without exec()?

Comment: I've figured out how this could be replicated without `exec()`. The `function()` class itself which functions are instances of can be constructed with a `code` object representing the body built as a string by `make_global_funcs`. 

I found a talk by Brandon Rhodes which outlines acceptable uses for `eval()` and `exec()` and the current usage of `exec()` by `turtle.py` mirrors the functionality of `namedtuple` construction, and is thus kosher in my eyes:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0No2zSJmks

Comment: After some more experimentation, as Rhodes mentions in regard to `namedtuple`, it's far more complex and takes longer to redefine methods as globals without explicitly using `exec()`, even more so to do so without using `compile()` with the arg `'exec'`, which might as well be `exec()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how this could be replicated without `exec()`... somewhat.

`exec()` is still necessary for assigning the old call signature to the new global functions in an explicit way, there is no convenient way to give a function a new call signature.

However, as an answer to my question, a closure works for making the methods into global functions, the call signature just has to be `*args, **kwargs`.

The following seems to work in the place of the code I posted and answers my question's title, how to replicate making methods global functions without exec, though I would argue it is not more pythonic due to the lack of accurate signatures:

```
def __turtle_func_closure(obj, init, name):
    """Wraps class methods as global functions."""

    def func(*args, **kwargs):
        """Global function equivalent ofor class methods."""
        obj_ = getattr(Turtle, obj, None)
        if obj_ is None:
            if not TurtleScreen._RUNNING:
                TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True
                raise Terminator
            obj_ = init()
        try:
            return getattr(obj_, name)(*args, **kwargs)
        except TK.TclError:
            if not TurtleScreen._RUNNING:
                TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True
                raise Terminator
            raise

    return func


def _make_global_funcs(functions, cls, obj, init, docrevise):
    for methodname in functions:
        method = getattr(cls, methodname)

        globals()[methodname] = __turtle_func_closure(obj, init, methodname)
        globals()[methodname].__doc__ = docrevise(method.__doc__)

_make_global_funcs(_tg_screen_functions, _Screen,
                   'Turtle._screen', Screen, _screen_docrevise)
_make_global_funcs(_tg_turtle_functions, Turtle,
                   'Turtle._pen', Turtle, _turtle_docrevise)
```