# Python: Define function with name from variable string

Tags: python, function, loops

I'm building a script which has multiple task loops, with different intervals.
Naturally I would want to make a for-loop to define all of these, to make it take up less space.
However, it seems like it's not possible to do so.

How can I shorten down this snippet?
Is there actually a way?

```
timeloops = ["60","600","3600","7200","14400","21600"]

@tasks.loop(seconds=60)
async def task_60(self):
    await second_func(self,channels["60"])

@tasks.loop(seconds=600)
async def task_600(self):
    await second_func(self,channels["600"])

@tasks.loop(seconds=3600)
async def task_3600(self):
    await second_func(self,channels["3600"])

@tasks.loop(seconds=7200)
async def task_7200(self):
    await second_func(self,channels["7200"])

@tasks.loop(seconds=14400)
async def task_14400(self):
    await second_func(self,channels["14400"])

@tasks.loop(seconds=21600)
async def task_21600(self):
    await second_func(self,channels["21600"])
```

Another question on here lead me to use Globals, but it seems like that's only for calling the function, and not for defining it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553721/using-a-string-variable-as-a-variable-name.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to test this since you didn't provide an MRE, but I think building them as a list should be doable:

```
task_loops = [
    tasks.loop(seconds=int(secs))(
        lambda self, secs=secs: (
            await second_func(self.channels[secs]) for _ in '_'
        ).__anext()
    ) for secs in timeloops
]
```

The part I'm a little fuzzy on is whether you can define an async lambda that way.  This should also work:

```
task_loops = []
for secs in timeloops:
    @tasks.loop(seconds=int(secs))
    async def task_secs(self, secs=secs):
        await second_func(self, channels[secs])
    task_loops.append(task_secs)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need them as methods on your class then you may be able to get it working by creating a parameterised version of your tasks method:

```
async def timed_task(self, t):
    await second_func(self, channels[t])
```

And then using the `functools.partialmethod` function to create the individual instances of the method (perhaps put this in the `__init__` of the class):

```
from functools import partialmethod

for t in timeloops:
    # Create the tasks.loop wrapper
    wrapper = tasks.loop(seconds=int(t))
    # Create the method to be wrapped
    wrapped = partialmethod(timed_task, t)
    setattr(self, f"task_{t}", wrapper(wrapped))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exec` to execute function definition and use string formatting to fill variables. You can try the following code.

```py
import inspect

timeloops = ["60", "600", "3600", "7200", "14400", "21600"]

for i in timeloops:
    define_func = f"""
    @tasks.loop(seconds=int(i))
    async def task_{i}(self):
        await second_func(self,channels[f"{i}"])
    """
    define_func = inspect.cleandoc(define_func)
    exec(define_func)
```

or the simpler way

```py
timeloops = ["60", "600", "3600", "7200", "14400", "21600"]

for i in timeloops:
    @tasks.loop(seconds=int(i))
    async def task(self, i=i):  # Prevent variable i from being overwritten
        await second_func(self,channels[i])

    exec(f'task_{i}=task')
```