# Change Python function at runtime

Tags: python

I have a string that contains a function name.

Using this string, how can I change the related function definition at run time?

This code updates the definition of the *first* function:

```
def first():
    print("first")
    
def second():
    print("second")
    
first = second

print(first)
print(second)
```

> <function second at 0x7f35b40c3840>
>
> <function second at 0x7f35b40c3840>

But that one doesn't:

```
def first():
    print("first")
    
def second():
    print("second")
    
func_to_change = "first"

eval_fist = eval(func_to_change)
exec('eval_fist = second')

print(eval_fist)
print(first)
```

> <function second at 0x7f35b40c3a60>
>
> <function first at 0x7f35b40c3840>

Comment: In the second code it doesn't look like you actually updated first, you only set `eval_first` equal to `first` in your code and then to `second` at runtime, the actual function `first` is not changed by your code.
So `eval_first` correctly shows that it is function `second` and `first` is still first, unchanged.

Comment: note that approaches with `eval` on user input are *extremely dangerous*

Comment: I'm not sure why you need `eval` and `exec` here. Functions are just objects. They are not different from variables. You can just assign a function's name to any other object you want. This seems like an XY-problem. Please try to give context of your ***real*** problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a string variable as a variable name (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11553721/6045800)

Comment: What, incidentally, are you trying to do?  Monkeypatch an imported module?  Have changed behaviour at runtime?  What is the function *used* for?  A more pythonic solution woud normally be to store a bunch of functions in a dict and then look up the right one, if all you want is to change which function gets called based on user input.

Comment: @Tomerikoo thanks it worked!

Comment: Then mark the question as duplicate

Answer (score 0):

```
locals()[func_tochange] = second
```

or

```
exec(f'{func_tochange} = second')
```

Comment: Apart from eval being bad, you can't use it like that. It will raise a syntax error. It's for expressions, not statements...

Comment: Sorry, I already corrected the code. Why is `eval` bad? It is a main feature of the language. I think it should be avoided when it is posibble, but not always is

Comment: [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/6045800)

Comment: I think eval can be used in a bad way. The main use of eval or exec is to evaluate code generated at runtime. And also it is not slow if it evaluates a previously compiled code.