# Python-Name a series of dataframes with a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I know this a basic question but I am trying to call data from the database and define each of these dataframes as different variables.

This is what i have tried

```
lst=['A','B','C']
for i in range(len(lst)):
    globals()[lst[i]]=***SQL query to import dataframes***
```

This is what I am looking for:

```
print(A)
*** Some Dataframe ***
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can use pandas to read the tables
import pandas as pd
pd.read_sql() : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html

Comment: You *really* shouldn't be dynamically creating variables. Just use a `dict`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a string variable as a variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553721/using-a-string-variable-as-a-variable-name)

Comment: Sorry, this does not answer my question but I will keep working on it

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can cycle through a sql query with different variables like this:

```
lst=['A','B','C']
for i in lst:
     f"""
     SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN1 = '{i}'
     """
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the `enumerate` function doing for loop through list.
This makes it possible for you to unpack the index, and the value of the current element. Like so:

```
lst=['A','B','C']
for index, value in enumerate(lst):
    # Do some code here
    pass
```

This is the pythonic way of looping through lists when accessing the values.
Hope this helps.