# Generating lists from a source list

Tags: python

I have a list of unique elements. I want to break it down into several lists so that each list has only one element of the original list and has a unique name based on the element index separately. Is there an idea to solve this issue?

```
lst = ['1', '2', '3']
```

the output must be:

```
lst_0 = ['1']
lst_1 = ['2']
lst_2 = ['3']
```

Comment: Hello. Can you show the code you have attempted so far to help point out where you are having issues exactly? Also, are you looking to create an arbitrary number of variables based on a varying length list? Or is it always a list of size 3?

Comment: Sound like an [x/y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), could you explain *why* you want to do this?

Comment: First of all, you don't really want separate variables. See [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/6045800). You want a list of lists. And that's pretty straight-forward: `res = [[x] for x in lst]`

Comment: Even then. If you want a variable number of variables that are representing elements of a list somehow, the answer here really is to use a dictionary instead which is explained in the link already provided in the previous comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1373185/1832539)

Comment: @idjaw Why to use a dictionary when the keys are just sequential integers (disregarding the meaningfulness of the `lst_` prefix)? That's just a glorified list...

Comment: @Tomerikoo - It all depends. In this example it is a sequential list. What do you do when it isn't sequential and you want a specific item in that list that you can want/need to get in `O(1)` time? I think overall it speaks to the clarity required in the question to understand what OP is really looking to do.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid variable names like this. Instead, use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)
like the one below. Initialize it using [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
lst = ['1', '2', '3']
dct = {f'lst_{i+1}': [x] for i, x in enumerate(lst)}
print(dct)
# {'lst_1': ['1'], 'lst_2': ['2'], 'lst_3': ['3']}

print(dct['lst_1'])
# ['1']
```

Or, if you want a more intuitive and, perhaps, more fitting data structure, use a list of lists, as suggsted in the comment by *Tomerikoo*. Initialize it using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
lst_of_lsts = [[x] for x in lst]
print(lst_of_lsts)
# [['1'], ['2'], ['3']]
print(lst_of_lsts[0])
# ['1']
```

**SEE ALSO:**

- [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/967621)
- [Using a string variable as a variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11553721/967621)

Comment: You can just do `enumerate(lst, 1)` to avoid the repeated additions. But also, this is hardly a use-case for a dict as the keys are non-unique strings of sequential nature. This really calls for a simple list-of-lists...

Comment: @matszwecja: Thx! Updated. I misread the question...

Comment: I wouldn't link the 2nd question. Most voted answer doesn't have enough of a disclaimer why exec/eval is a terribly bad idea in that case.

Comment: Simplify further - `dct = {f'lst_{i}': [x] for i, x in enumerate(lst, 1)}`

Answer (score 1):

> the output must be:

```
lst_1 = ['1']
lst_2 = ['2']
lst_3 = ['3']
```

So you want to output all the elements in your `list` with a particular format, right?

```
for index, value in enumerate(lst):
    print(f"lst_{index} = ['{value}']")
```

This will give you exactly the expected output.

---

If you really want to create a `list of lists` out of a `list`, you can do this:

```
>>> print([[x] for x in lst])
[['1'], ['2'], ['3']]
```

---

For sure there are far more elegant ways of doing this, I'm just answering the question as it is.

Comment: what if I want to append the results in a new list?

Comment: You can use list.copy()