# How do I append to a list when the name of the list lies within a string?

Tags: python, append

I've got multiple lists:

```
    list_1 = []
    list_2 = []
    list_3 = []
```

And I've got the following string, which depending on the circumstances will correspond to one of the lists above:

```
    x = 'list_2'
```

How do I go about appending to the list by using the string? Is there any way I can do something along the lines of:

```
    'value of x'.append("Whatever")
```

Comment: If I understand you requirement right, then you use a dictionary of lists.

Comment: You should use dict instead of multiple variables.

Comment: Are you looking for canonically-bad-idea [variable variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/3001761)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dictionary of lists. Do not use `eval` if you can avoid it (it is dangerous), and yours is a classic case where you can avoid it.

```
dct = {'list_1': [],
       'list_2': [],
       'list_3': [],}

x = 'list_2'
print(dct[x])
# []
```

**SEE ALSO:**

- [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/967621)
- [How can you dynamically create variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5036700/967621)
- [Using a string variable as a variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11553721/967621)

Comment: Rather than "see also: 3 obvious dupes", _vote to close as dupe_.

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> list_1 = []
>>> list_2 = []
>>> list_3 = []
>>> x = 'list_2'
>>> eval(x).append("whatever")
>>> list_2
['whatever']
```

Comment: Please include an explanation with your answer to help readers understand how this works, and solves the problem. You can click the edit button at the bottom of your answer to add an explanation. Additionally, you may find it beneficial reading [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

you can use [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

```
list_1 = [1,2,3]
list_2 = [4,5,6]
list_3 = [7,8,9]

x = 'list_2'
print(eval(x))
```

Output:

```
[4, 5, 6]
```