# Defining same method override on lots of classes: DRY?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have a large number of classes defined by an `import` of a large library codebase, which I don't want to hack around with for reasons of maintainability. They all inherit from BaseClass, and BaseClass contains a method which I want to augment. I think the following is a workable solution

```
class MyMixin(object):
   def method( self, args):  
      ... # 1. a few lines of code copied from BaseClass's def of method
      ... # 2. some lines of my code that can't go before or after the copied code
      ... # 3. and the rest of the copied code

class MyAbcClass( MyMixin, AbcClass): 
   pass
# many similar lines
class MyZzzClass( MyMixin, ZzzClass): 
   pass
```

The question. Is there a way to take, say,  a list of `("MyXxxClass", XxxClass)` tuples, and write code that defines the MyXxxClasses? And is it sufficiently comprehensible that it beats the repetition in the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use three-arg [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) to define the classes, then set them on [the module's global dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933470/how-do-i-call-setattr-on-the-current-module):

```
todefine = [('MyAbcClass', AbcClass), ...]
for name, base in todefine:
    globals()[name] = type(name, (MyMixin, base), {})
```

If the names to define follow the fixed pattern you gave (`"My" + base class name), you can repeat yourself even less by dynamically constructing the name to define:

```
todefine = [AbcClass, ...]
for base in todefine:
    name = "My" + base.__name__
    globals()[name] = type(name, (MyMixin, base), {})
```

And if you are trying to wrap all the classes from a given module, you can avoid even explicitly listing the classes by introspecting the module to generate `todefine` programmatically (if you know the module has or lacks `__all__` you can just use the appropriate approach instead of trying one and defaulting to the other):

```
import inspect
try:
    # For modules that define __all__, we want all exported classes
    # even if they weren't originally defined in the module
    todefine = filter(inspect.isclass, (getattr(somemodule, name) for name in somemodule.__all__))
except AttributeError:
    # If __all__ not defined, heuristic approach; exclude private names
    # defined with leading underscore, and objects that were imported from
    # other modules (so if the module does from itertools import chain,
    # we don't wrap chain)
    todefine = (obj for name, obj in vars(somemodule).items() if not name.startswith('_') and inspect.isclass(obj) and inspect.getmodule(obj) is somemodule)
```

Comment: It gets better: `"My"+AbcClass.__name__` is the string `"MyAbcClass" so I can input just a list of classes to derive Myclasses from.

Comment: I was considering mentioning that; I wasn't sure if the names were really as a simple as `"My" + base.__name__` though. If you're wrapping every class from another given module, you could even dynamically pull them, by defining `todefine = (obj for name, obj in vars(somemodule).items() if not name.startswith('_') and inspect.isclass(obj) and inspect.getmodule(obj) is somemodule)`.

Comment: @nigel222: I added some info to the answer on this.