# python: use different function depending on os

Tags: python, cross-platform

I want to write a script that will execute on Linux and Solaris. Most of the logic will be identical on both OS, therefore I write just one script. But because some deployed structure will differ (file locations, file formats, syntax of commands), a couple of functions will be different on the two platforms.

This could be dealt with like

```
if 'linux' in sys.platform:
    result = do_stuff_linux()
if 'sun' in sys.platform:
    result = do_stuff_solaris()
more_stuf(result)
...
```

However it seems to cumbersome and unelegant to sprinkle these `ifs` throughout the code. Also I could register functions in some `dict` and then call functions via the dict. Probably a little nicer.

Any better ideas on how this could be done?

Comment: calling them via dictionary will be better

Comment: Assuming the functions both serve the same purpose, you could also put them in OS-specific modules and `import` the appropriate set of functions using an `if` statement. The drawback is that you would need to ensure the signatures (function names, input arguments and output) match.

Comment: @Kendas I like that approach, seems most elegant to me. The drawback for me is that I would need to ship more than one file. Maybe that is not such a big deal though, I need to think about it.

Comment: I'm working on an answer that addresses that last problem, hang on

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

You create separate files for each of the functions you need to duplicate and import the right one:

```
import sys
if 'linux' in sys.platform:
    from .linux import prepare, cook
elif 'sun' in sys.platform:
    from .sun import prepare, cook
else:
    raise RuntimeError("Unsupported operating system: {}".format(sys.platform))

dinner = prepare('pork')
drink_wine()
result = cook(dinner)
```

**Solution 1.5:**

If you need to keep everything in a single file, or just don't like the conditional import, you can always just create aliases for the functions like so:

```
import sys

def prepare_linux(ingredient):
    ...

def prepare_sun(ingredient):
    ...

def cook_linux(meal):
    ...

def cook_sun(meal):
    ...

if 'linux' in sys.platform:
    prepare = prepare_linux
    cook = cook_linux
elif 'sun' in sys.platform:
    prepare = prepare_sun
    cook = cook_sun
else:
    raise RuntimeError("Unsupported operating system: {}".format(sys.platform))

dinner = prepare('chicken')
drink_wine()
result = cook(dinner)
```

Comment: I like that. And with some more python magic, one could probably even get rid of the if/elif in the alias defintion. I will post back if I come up with something.

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933470/how-do-i-call-setattr-on-the-current-module), you could try to use `sys.modules['__main__']`, but really that seems to be more like cleverness for cleverness' sake, unless you have a truly massive amount of duplicated functions. At that point, you might consider the module approach.

Comment: Great answer! How would this work for Windows or Mac?

Comment: @Chaky31 - Try looking at the documentation of [`sys.platform`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.platform) for examples of possible values. There are values for Mac and Windows in there as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
if 'linux' in sys.platform:
    def do_stuff():
        result = # do linux stuff
        more_stuff(result)
elif 'sun' in sys.platform:
    def do_stuff():
        result = # do solaris stuff
        more_stuff(result)
```

And then simply call `do_stuff()`.