# How can I apply a fucntion over a set of numbered files and get outputs numbered same way using python?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am analyzing a series of molecular dynamic trajectories,

```
traj1
traj2 
traj3
...
```

I want to apply an analysis function to all them separately so that I get the different outputs also numbered

```
output1
output2
output3
...
```

Either that Or

```
traj1_output
traj2_output
traj3_output
```

I was trying to write a loop, but couldnt really find the way.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you perhaps show the loop you tried to write?

Comment: Hi, yes sure, 
I was trying somthing like this,

for i in range(len(traj_list)):
    topology_%d = traj_list[i].top % (i)

Not sure if this makes sense I have very little Python experience.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can write function for one element and then use `map()` built-in function.
Linc to documetation https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that what you're trying to do is map inputs to outputs. While you can create variables on the fly with programmatically created names (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933470/how-do-i-call-setattr-on-the-current-module/2933481#2933481)), it is perhaps clearer to just use a `dict`:

```
def process(data):
    return "processed: {data}".format(data=data)

trajectories = {
    "traj1": "some data",
    "traj2": "some data",
    "traj3": "some data",
}

results = {}
for name in trajectories:
    output_name = "{name}_output".format(name=name)
    results[output_name] = process(trajectories[name])

# Print out all results (in semi-random order)
for name in results:
    print("{name}: {result}".format(name=name, result=results[name]))

# Print out a result from the dict
print(results["traj1_output"])
```

Note that the stub functions and values are there just so you can play around with the concept without the need for some complicated algorithm in your real program.