# How to define a CSV data as a variable in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to import a CSV file data and define the first value of each line as a variable to a class object or a dict. I managed to create dictionaries from imported data, but can access them individually. Any enlightenment? Thank you.

CSV type:

name,gender,age,country,location

John,M,53,Brazil,São Paulo

```
import csv

file = "info.csv"
csv_open = open(file, newline="")
csv_data = csv.reader(csv_open)

data = []

for line in csv_data: # All CSV data as a list
    data.append(line)

class Person:

    """Simple register with name, gender, age, country and
    location info."""

    def __init__(self, name, gender, age, country, location):
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender
        self.age = age
        self.country = country
        self.location = location

idx = 0

for elem in data:

    *problem_here_no_var* = Person( data[idx][0],
                                    data[idx][1],
                                    data[idx][2],
                                    data[idx][3],
                                    data[idx][4])
    idx += 1

print(John.country)
#My intention is to access a specific object and return any of it's attributes.
```

Comment: Use a *container*, not dynamically generated variables.

Comment: Also, you are already looping through your data, there's no reason to manually keep track of an index. So, `for elem in data:`, don't use `data[idx][0]`, use `elem[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using csv. Dictreader and either setting the headers yourself or just using your csv headers.  Something like this

```
person_data = []
        with open(file, newline = '') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                temp_person = Person(row['name'], row['gender'], row['age'], row['country'], row['location'])
                person_data.append(temp_person)
```

Now you have a list of Person objects that have already been initialized and you can do whatever you want with that list after.

checkout https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

DictReader and Writer get used fairly often.

as your code is now for the person object you need to add a

```
__str__ method so you can print the values of the person
```

example

```
def __str__(self):
return self.name + self.age.....
```

Now you can call

```
for person in person_data:
    print(person)
# can also do print(person.name) to get name can be done for any field.
```

And this will print whatever you defined in the **str** function.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Dathan Ault-McCoy](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-dynamically-create-variables-in-Python), you can do this using the __ dict __ dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can set attributes on the current module dynamically. See [How do I call setattr() on the current module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933470/how-do-i-call-setattr-on-the-current-module)

The idea being that you use the string from the first column as the attribute name.

That being said, I'm not sure why you would need to set a variable to have an unknown name since it would be difficult to access it later without knowing it's name.