# How to use from x import y using importlib in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package, python-import

I wanted to install and import a package from script. Then I wanted to add `from x import y` and `from x import *` in that script.*(I was making some functions actually)*.

I successfully installed and imported using `subprocess` and `importlib`. But I'm at a loss in `from x import y` and `from x import *`. Tried these codes and some others.

```
globals()[package] = importlib.import_module('package','class')
globals()[package] = importlib.import_module('class','package')
globals()[package] = importlib.import_module('package','*')
globals()[package] = importlib.import_module('*','package')
importlib.import_module('gtts','gTTS')
importlib.import_module('gtts','*')
```

But they didn't work. Shows:

```
NameError: name 'gTTS' is not defined
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gTTS'
```

etc.

Comment: I think you need to assign it to a variable, as you did with globals: `mod=importlib.import_module('gtts','gTTS')` and then use something like `mod.gTTS(args)` to call it

Comment: yes I did. See [package]. It means the imported data name. And I wrote global because I was making a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can load methods directly, since this method just loads modules. A module is loaded with `import module` and i defined as "A module is a file containing Python definitions and statements. The file name is the module name with the suffix .py appended. " (check [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)). `from x import y` does also do the `import module` but sets another namespace (see discussion [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187403/import-module-vs-from-module-import-function)). What you can do is load your module and then set your namespace manually afterwards, this is what the `from x import y syntax` does. You can load a module with the path (in this example i want to load `read_csv` from pandas):

```
importlib.import_module(".io.parsers", "pandas")
```

(check the path with `print(inspect.getmodule(read_csv).__name__)`)

Also a solution like [jottbe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6925185/jottbe) mentioned in the commentary would be possible

Answer (score 5):

The exact syntax to correspond to mischva11's answer, is as follows:

```
tempmod = importlib.import_module("x_mymodule")
y = x_mymodule.y
del tempmod  # optionally delete the reference to the parent module
```

Imports only the attribute `y` from the module `x_mymod`, similar to `from x_mymodule import y`.  You can get the `... as z` functionality by assigning it to any name you want in the 2nd line of code.

I found it useful to delete the parent module from the namespace, when using this in a sub-module, to prevent cluttering up the namespace.

I think to get the `import *` function you'll have to iterate through the module's attributes and assign them to a named attribute.  Here are two hints that help you get there:

- [How to list all functions in a Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139180/how-to-list-all-functions-in-a-python-module)
- Set attributes of module from inside the module: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2933481/2453202