# Getting the value of a variable when I only have the variable name as a string

Tags: python

```
x = 14

variable_name = 'x'
```

How can I get the value of x when I only have the name of it as a string?

Comment: I looks like you should use a dict rather than resorting to ugly tricks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vars()`:

```
vars()[variable_name]
```

Which gives the variables of the scope it's called at [(Source)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2933481/11659881).