# Python module as global instance of class

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [**getattr** on a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447353/getattr-on-a-module)

I have a module which defines a Manager class in it.  I would like the module to create an instance of this class and have the module serve as a "global instance" of this class.  For example:

```
class Manager:

    def func(self):
        print('stuff')

instance = Manager()

def func():
    instance.func()
```

Is there a way to make module.x returns module.instance.x? (kind of like a module level property)

UPDATE:  The answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447353/getattr-on-a-module) covers only half of my use case (i.e., it is NOT a duplicate, what that question is asking is different); I also need the module's attribute to also be available.  Example:

```
class Manager:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 3

    def func(self):
        print('stuff')

sys.modules[__name__] = Manager()

>>> module.func
<func>
>>> module.x
3
>>> module.Manager
AttributeError
```

Comment: If you don't need any fancy class functionality like `__getattr__` then why not simply use module-level functions instead of methods?

Comment: I need "fancy class functionality" such as subclassing/inheritance and making more instances.  I know it seems like I want a singleton, but I don't.  I want a regular class whose module has a "global instance" of it.

Comment: In that case consider writing functions that would delegate to the main instance. You could also simply do `foo = instance.foo` for each method.

Comment: `instance.foo = 3; foo = instance.foo; instance.foo = 4; foo == 3 and instance.foo = 4`  I considered writing functions, but that would mean a set and a get for EACH attribute.  Lots of bloat.

Comment: Oy, I specifically edited my question to state that this is NOT a duplicate of the getattr question, yet it is marked as duplicate?  What is wrong with you people?

Comment: Look at what Python's `logging` class does. Define the class and create an instance of the class within the module. `import logging; logging.getLogger().warn(...)` can be called in every file that you want to have logging for, and they will all share the same instance as long as you access it via `logging.getLogger()` instead of creating a local instance in your file (ie, don't do `log = logging.getLogger()`)

Comment: @IceArdor I think that's a nice idea, I was thinking the same because I also use `logging`...but maybe not really fair to @darkfeline because the module `logging` already has a `getLogger` defined and for `Manager` it is not just available.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the `Manager`'s `__getattr__` return module-level objects?

```
def __getattr__(self, key):
    try:
        return globals()[key]
    except KeyError:
        raise AttributeError(key)
```

Comment: If I subclass `Manager` or make another instance of it, that `__getattr__` wouldn't make sense.