# How to customize module attribute reference behavior in Python

Tags: python

I know I can customize class attribute access by defining `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__`, but can I do it for a certain module?

For example, `foo` is an imported module and `x` is any name not defined in `foo`. Can I make `foo.x` return 'Hello' instead of Python throwing AttributeError, no matter what `x` not defined in `foo` is referenced?

**Edit 03/12/2020**

This feature was added to [Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#pep-562-customization-of-access-to-module-attributes)

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python

Comment: Probably a bad idea unless you have a very good reason to do this but see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2447383/1222578)