# Cross module variable sharing without duplicating imports

Tags: python, python-2.7, scope, python-module

I have a module `models.py` with some data logic:

```
db = PostgresqlDatabase(database='database', user='user')

# models logic
```

and flask app which actually interacts with database:

```
from models import db, User, ...
```

But I want to move initializing all setting from one config file in flask app:

So I could separate importing `db` from other stuff (I need this for access to module variable `db` in `models`):

```
import models
from models import User, ...
app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])
models.db = PostgresqlDatabase(database=app.config['db'],
                               user=app.config['db'])
```

and use further `db` as `models.db`

But seems it is kinda ugly. Duplicating imports, different usage of module stuff..

Is there any better way how to handle this situation?

Comment: `from somewhere import db` is terrible -- it means db can never be reinitialised, thus your app cannot change config on the fly. It also makes unit-testing much harder, you end up mocking out same db in many modules.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend 1 level of indirection, so that your code becomes like this:

```
import const
import runtime

def foo():
    runtime.db.execute("SELECT ... LIMIT ?", (..., const.MAX_ROWS))
```

You get:

- clear separation of leaf module `const`
- mocking and/or reloading is possible
- uniform and concise access in all user modules

To get rich API on `runtime`, use the "replace module with object at import" trick ( see [__getattr__ on a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447353/getattr-on-a-module/7668273#7668273) )