# Python: __getattr__ for a module object

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Supposing, I have a python module called `mymodule`, it has the following structure:

```
""" mymodule.py """

mydata = {
    "x": 12,
    "y": 58
}
```

I want to access to data in the following way:

```
""" main.py """
import mymodule

print(mymodule.x) # 12
print(mymodule.y) # 58
```

What should I add to `mymodule.py`?

I would like to know solutions for `Python 2.7` and `Python 3`.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984647/accessing-dict-keys-like-an-attribute-in-python

Comment: @UriShalit I need a solution for a module, not for a class.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447353/getattr-on-a-module - pretty comprehensive answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\_\_getattr\_\_ on a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447353/getattr-on-a-module)

Answer (score 1):

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/7668273/783836, it seems to can be done by replacing the module with a class that does what you want:

```
# module foo.py

import sys

class Foo:
    def funct1(self, <args>): <code>
    def funct2(self, <args>): <code>

sys.modules[__name__] = Foo()
```

Check the entire post for full details

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1

If the only data is `x` and `y` and you don't want it dynamic you can do something like:

```
""" mymodule.py """

mydata = {
    "x": 12,
    "y": 58
}

x = mydata['x']
y = mydata['y']
```

## Option 2

Another option is to use `addict.Dict` but this will require a bit of change in the import.

```
""" mymodule.py """
from addict import Dict

mydata = Dict({
    "x": 12,
    "y": 58
})
```

And then to use it:

```
""" main.py""
from mymodule import mydata

print(mydata.x)
print(mydata.y)
```

It would be more easier to know why you need it...