# Python __getattr__ executed multiple times

Tags: python, getattr

I've been trying to implement the `__getattr__` function as in the following example:

[PEP 562 -- Module `__getattr__` and `__dir__`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/#rationale)

And I don't get why this simple piece of code:

```
# lib.py

def __getattr__(name):
    print(name)

# main.py

from lib import test
```

outputs:

```
__path__
test
test
```

What is `__path__` ? Why is it sent to `__getattr__` ? Why is `test` sent 2 times ?

Comment: `__path__` is part of the import mechanism. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2699287/1126841.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you know why ```test``` is sent 2 times ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*TL;DR the first "test" printed is a side-effect of the "from import" implementation, i.e. it's printed during creation of `lib` module. The second "test" is from subsequent access of dynamic attribute on the module directly.*

Knowing that [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) is implemented in Python code, modify your `lib.py` slightly to also dump a trace:

```
# lib.py
from traceback import print_stack

def __getattr__(name):
    print_stack()
    print(name)
    print("-" * 80)
```

This gives the hint to pinpoint the library location in importlib which triggers double attribute access:

```
$ python3 main.py 
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from lib import test
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1019, in _handle_fromlist
  File "/private/tmp/lib.py", line 5, in __getattr__
    print_stack()
__path__
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from lib import test
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1032, in _handle_fromlist
  File "/private/tmp/lib.py", line 5, in __getattr__
    print_stack()
test
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from lib import test
  File "/private/tmp/lib.py", line 5, in __getattr__
    print_stack()
test
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now we can find the answer easily by RTFS (below I use Python v3.7.6, switch on git to the exact tag you use in case of different version). Look in [`importlib._bootstrap. _handle_fromlist`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.6/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py#L1009-L1044) at the indicated line numbers.

`_handle_fromlist` is a helper intended to load package submodules in a `from` import. Step 1 is to see if the module is a package at all:

```
if hasattr(module, '__path__'):
```

The `__path__` access comes there, on line 1019. Because your `__getattr__` returns `None` for all inputs, `hasattr` returns `True` here, so your module looks like a package, and the code continues on. (If `hasattr` had returned `False`, `_handle_fromlist` would abort at this point.)

The "fromlist" here will have the name you requested, `["test"]`, so we go into the for-loop with `x="test"` and on line 1032 there is the "extra" invocation:

```
elif not hasattr(module, x):
```

`from lib import test` will only attempt to load a `lib.test` submodule if `lib` does not already have a `test` attribute. This check is testing whether the attribute exists, to see if `_handle_fromlist` needs to attempt to load a submodule.

Should you return different values for the first and second invocation of `__getattr__` with name "test", then the second value returned is the one which will actually be received within `main.py`.