# how to create top-level module function from another function?

Tags: python

Given a module `mymodule` with an `__init__.py` file how can I define a functions of mymodule from another function within that file?

`__init__.py` code outline:

```
def a():
    THISMODULE.__dict__["b"] = lambda: print("this is not weird")

a()
b() # Expect "this is not weird" output
```

`mymodule` comes as a replacement for `anothermodule` and I want to make the code change as simple as replacing `import anothermodule as thething` with `import mymodule as thething`. Since I don't implement all the functions of `anothermodule` just yet, I would like to send the user a notification about it instead of crashing with "not defined".

Comment: Does the name have to be dynamic? If not simply `global b` and `b = lambda...` will work fine. What's the context - what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I don't know the names upfront and have to access them through the `__dict__`

Comment: But *why* - again, could you expand on the context?

Comment: I'd like to mock another module. Mock every function with a swallow-all stabs and a few with something more elaborate.

Comment: Please [edit] to elaborate, that seems like a test/architecture smell.

Comment: Updated the info with the purpose of the that change

Comment: In that case why not `from anothermodule import *` until you've overridden everything? Or if that won't work, use a module-level `__getattr__` per e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2447353/3001761.

Comment: functions of `anothermodule` would not work any longer. __getattr__ is good suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`__name__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__name__) is a module attribute set by the import machinery, which evaluates to the name of the current module. Adding this to the top of your file:

```
import sys

THISMODULE = sys.modules[__name__]
```

And the rest of what you already have should work correctly.