# How to raise a DeprecationWarning when catching an exception with python?

Tags: python, exception, deprecation-warning

I wrote a library that sometimes raises exceptions. There is an exception that I want to deprecate, and I would like to advise people to stop catching them, and provide advises in the warning message. But how to make an exception emit a `DeprecationWarning` when catched?

## library code

```
import warnings

class MyException(ValueError):
    ...
    warnings.warn(
        "MyException is deprecated and will soon be replaced by `ValueError`.",
        DeprecationWarning,
        stacklevel=2,
    )
    ...

def something():
    raise MyException()
```

## user code

```
try:
    mylib.something()
except MyException: # <-- raise a DeprecationWarning here
    pass
```

How can I modify `MyException` to achieve this?

Comment: user myexeption or library code>

Comment: You've edited your question to make it so there's no clear transition path. `except MyException` is deprecated, but there's no good alternative for users to use instead.

Comment: Related: [module `__getattr__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447353/getattr-on-a-module).

Comment: The question is, if catching this exception is deprecated, what else should your users do?

Answer (score 10):

You can't. None of the logic that occurs in `except MyException` is customizable. Particularly, it completely ignores things like `__instancecheck__` or `__subclasscheck__`, so you can't hook into the process of determining whether an exception matches an exception class.

The closest you can get is having the warning happen when a user tries to access your exception class with `from yourmodule import MyException` or `yourmodule.MyException`. You can do that with a module `__getattr__`:

```
class MyException(ValueError):
    ...

# access _MyException instead of MyException to avoid warning
# useful if other submodules of a package need to use this exception
# also use _MyException within this file - module __getattr__ won't apply.
_MyException = MyException
del MyException

def __getattr__(name):
    if name == 'MyException':
        # issue warning
        return _MyException
    raise AttributeError
```

Comment: Won't work as written.   `__getattr__` is only invoked if the name is not found by the normal means.

Comment: @wim: Oh, whoops - I meant to have a `del MyException` there, but I forgot to write it. Fixed now.

Comment: +1 This is the correct way, and deprecating names is actually the first [rationale given in the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/#rationale) for the module `__getattr__` feature.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this:

```
import warnings


class MyOtherException(Exception):
    pass


class MyException(MyOtherException):
    def __init__(self):
        warnings.warn(
            "MyException is deprecated and will soon be replaced by `MyOtherException`.",
            DeprecationWarning,
            stacklevel=2,
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        mylib.something()
    except Exception:
        raise MyException()
```

Comment: I can only edit the `library code` and not the `user code`, so I cannot assume anything going in the except block. No guarantee that the user will raise a `MyException`

Comment: This is missing the point. User code might catch `MyException` class without ever instantiating one.