# try except every AttributeError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I don't want to silence any errors. I want to make a cool package.

Ever do this:

```
readline.getbegidx()
```

AttributeError!!!!11!!

"Oh it's actually..."

```
readline.get_begidx()
```

I want to make a package that fuzzy matches attributes to callables whenever there's an attribute error. I ***DONT*** want to silence any errors or exceptions.

So that when you do:

```
readline.getbegidx()
```

It does:

```
#AttributeError: getbegidx() doesn't exist but get_begidx() does.
#You probably mistyped this attribute name, assuming you meant:
readline.get_begidx()
```

So what I want to do is to catch every single attribute error and search through the attributes and if the similarity is above something like 98% match, but if not raise the exception, without the user having to do:

```
try:
except:
try:
except:
try:
except:
...
```

everywhere.

So I want to:

1. Detect if an AttributeError occurs
2. Catch it, get the attribute that was used
3. If there was a similar attribute, apply that to the original code / replace it
4. Run the function

Comment: You could use **__getattr__** for non existent attributes. Then search the dict of the class for an attribute with similar name.

Comment: Thanks! Could you use that in an example? So it's `module.__getatttr__`? I don't think so because it's giving me an error. Yes I plan on using dir(module), but what I'm asking is how to catch every `AttributeError` exception to then run that code.

Comment: Here is an answer how to use it in a module: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48916205/8664416

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Yeah this will be useful for when I create a new module and in my module I want to maybe get all attributes but what I wanted was to get all attributes of any imported module, rather than my own modules.