# __getattr__ for module running twice on import?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, getattr

I'm trying to run some logic when objects are imported from a module by using `__getattr__` as described here: [__getattr__ on a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447353/getattr-on-a-module)

...but the logic runs twice. Why is that happening and how can I stop it?

[image]

`main.py`

```
from test import x, y
```

`test.py`

```
def __getattr__(name: str):
    print(f"Imported {name}")
```

Comment: Please post your code and output as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: Have you tried checking the traceback during the calls?

Comment: @o11c there's no traceback, since the code executes successfully. Running python in verbose mode doesn't reveal any information when I reproduce this locally. Checking the cProfile shows 5 calls to `test.__getattr__`: `5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 test.py:1(__getattr__)`

Comment: @C.Nivs The dupe shows how to check the traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `__getattr__` returns `None` for all attributes, including `__path__`, and if a module has a `__path__` attribute, it's treated as a package.

For a package, `from test import x, y` needs to handle possible submodules named `test.x` and `test.y`. The [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.2/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py#L1055) that does this handling uses `hasattr` first, to test whether `test` already has `x` and `y` attributes:

```
elif not hasattr(module, x):
    ...
```

and that `hasattr` is responsible for the first `__getattr__('x')` and `__getattr__('y')` calls.

The second `__getattr__('x')` and `__getattr__('y')` calls are just the ones you'd expect to happen, to retrieve `test.x` and `test.y` for the import.

---

Your `__getattr__` shouldn't return a value for special attributes like `__path__`.

Also, unrelated, naming a module `test` is a bad idea, because the standard library already claimed that name for [Python's own test suite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/test.html).

Comment: "Your __getattr__ returns None for all attributes, including __path__" is there any way for me to prevent this? I still want to make my logic only run once, but I'm not sure how to make `hasattr` return `False` for `__path__` here

Comment: Nevermind, just had to add `raise AttributeError` in the case that `name=='__path__'`