# Writing XML files with Python

Tags: python, xml

I have created an XML document with the following contents.

```
<books>
  <book id="1">
    <title>Title01</title>
    <authors/>
    <pages>
      <page>Page01</page>
      <page>Page02</page>
      <page>Page03</page>
      <page>Page04</page>
      <page>Page05</page>
    </pages>
  </book>
  <book id="2">
    <title>Title02</title>
    <authors/>
    <pages>
      <page>Page01</page>
      <page>Page02</page>
      <page>Page03</page>
      <page>Page04</page>
      <page>Page05</page>
    </pages>
  </book>
</books>
```

I then use a Python script to split up and write the individual books into separate files;however, the resulting files are not XML files because they do not have the XML declaration. Is there a way of creating XML files in Python?

The idea is to ensure that each file has the XML declaration as show below.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
  <book id="1">
    <title>Title01</title>
    <authors/>
    <pages>
      <page>Page01</page>
      <page>Page02</page>
      <page>Page03</page>
      <page>Page04</page>
      <page>Page05</page>
    </pages>
  </book>
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Best XML writing tool for python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56229/best-xml-writing-tool-for-python)

Comment: The XML declaration is not required for XML well-formedness (see http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-prolog).  Do you have another reason for needing it?

Comment: @Paul Butcher: Thank you for the response. I was rather hoping that I could have declaration to explicitly specify the encoding used. Also, I might find myself using the linux "find" command at some point to check if the file type is XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you write the xml declaration to each book file before you write the book entry?

Comment: I suppose this will do for now. Thank you very much.

Comment: great! what? 0 for the answer you liked?

Answer (score 0):

Encode your files in `UTF-8` instead of some legacy encoding like `ISO-8859-1`. Then you don't need an XML declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) module. The link is for Python 3, but it was included way before that. I use it in Python 2.5, so you should be ok.

Also, I have had good results with `xml.dom.minidom`. Once you have built a `Document` (by adding elements with `createElement('ELEM_NAME')`, you just write it to a stream with `mydoc.toprettyxml()`.